# Python, logging print statements while having them print to stdout

Tags: python, logging, printing, stdout

I have a long python script that uses print statements often, I was wondering if it was possible to add some code that would log all of the print statements into a text file or something like that. I still want all of the print statements to go to the command line as the user gets prompted throughout the program. If possible logging the user's input would be beneficial as well.

I found this which somewhat answers my question but makes it where the "print" statement no longer prints to the command line

[Redirect Python 'print' output to Logger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11124093/redirect-python-print-output-to-logger)

Comment: @Robᵩ [ha ha ha](http://www.troll.me/images/brick-tamland/you-think-youre-funny-but-youre-not.jpg)

Comment: @Stephan - I don't think I'm funny. I'm trying to understand what OP actually wants from us.

Comment: @Robᵩ i think he's asking how make `print "hi"` go to two different places with 1 statement

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can add this to your script:

```
import sys
sys.stdout = open('logfile', 'w')
```

This will make the print statements write to `logfile`.

If you want the option of printing to `stdout` and a file, you can try this:

```
class Tee(object):
    def __init__(self, *files):
        self.files = files
    def write(self, obj):
        for f in self.files:
            f.write(obj)

f = open('logfile', 'w')
backup = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = Tee(sys.stdout, f)

print "hello world"  # this should appear in stdout and in file
```

To revert to just printing to console, just restore the "backup"

```
sys.stdout = backup
```

Answer (score 10):

Here is a program that does what you describe:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

class Tee:
    def write(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.out1.write(*args, **kwargs)
        self.out2.write(*args, **kwargs)
    def __init__(self, out1, out2):
        self.out1 = out1
        self.out2 = out2

import sys
sys.stdout = Tee(open("/tmp/log.txt", "w"), sys.stdout)

print("hello")
```

Comment: why did you both use a class, and why are they both called `Tee`?

Comment: I used a class because `print` will eventually invoke `sys.stdout.write()`. Since I am replacing `sys.stdout`, my replacement needs to have a `.write()`.  I called it `Tee` after the [unix `tee` program](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tee), which is itself named after the [plumbing fixture of the same name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plumbing_fittings#Tee).

Comment: Interesting. Did you also run my program standalone, without any of your code? Did it produce a non-empty `/tmp/log.txt` then?

Comment: @reddman -  You might try adding `self.out1.flush()` and `self.out2.flush()` to `Tee.write():`.

Answer (score 5):

When trying the best answer accepted on python 3.7 I had the following exception:

```
    Exception ignored in: <__main__.Logger object at 0x7f04083760f0>
    AttributeError: 'Logger' object has no attribute 'flush'
```

I added the following function to make it work:

```
    def flush(self):
        pass
```

Answer (score 3):

If you use the built in [logging module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) you can configure your loggers with as many outputs as you need: to file,  to databases, to emails, etc. However it sounds like you're mixing print for two different uses:  logging (recording program flow for later inspection) and prompts.  The real work will be to split out those two uses of 'print' into different functions so you get what you need in each place.

A lot of people [replace python's generic sys.stdout and sys.stderr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/616645/how-do-i-duplicate-sys-stdout-to-a-log-file-in-python)  to automatically do stuff to text which is being sent to the console. The real console output always lives in `sys.__stdout__` and `sys.__stderr__` (so you don't need to worry about somehow 'losing' it) but if you stick any object with the same methods as a file into the variables `sys.stdout` and `sys.stderr` you can do whatever you like with the output process.

Answer (score -2):

hm... is it hard to implement your own print() function and decorator that will log anything that is passed to your print function?

```
def logger(func):
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        log(*args, **kwargs)  # your logging logic
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return inner

@logger
def lprint(string_to_print):
    print(string_to_print)
```