# Python - Automatically writing all print statements to a log fil

Tags: python, logging, printing

I have a scripts that contains lots of print statements along the process, here is an example:

```
import pandas
print "pandas library imported"
df = pd.Dataframe(...)
print "df created."

print "There are {0} rows and {1} columns in the data frame".format(df.shape[0], df.shape[1])

...
```

So is there a way that I can put all the print statements in a log file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python, logging print statements while having them print to stdout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17866724/python-logging-print-statements-while-having-them-print-to-stdout)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace `stdout` with your log file:

```
import sys
sys.stdout = open('log.txt', 'r')

import pandas

print "pandas library imported"
df = pd.Dataframe(...)
print "df created."
```

Output `log.txt`:

```
pandas library imported
df created.
```

Comment: Thanks Peter. This way hides all the print statement while running the process, is there a way that I can still printing out the messages on the command line?

Comment: @thatMeow See answers to the linked duplicate above

Answer (score 0):

Use `from __future__ import print_function` and call `print` with the `file` keyword-argument.

Alternatively, redirect the output of your script to a file in your shell.