# logging.info only writes format in stdout

Tags: python, logging, stdout, error-logging

I have a python script that prints debug and error outputs to `stdout` with `print()`. Now I want to retroactively add writing said output to a logfile, so I found [logging - Redirect Python 'print' output to Logger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17682520/12209580):

```py
import logging

# this is a hack to log print statements to a file
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format="%(asctime)s %(message)s")
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.addHandler(logging.FileHandler('logfile.log', 'a'))
logger.propagate = False
print = logger.info

# testing it:
print("test")
logger.info("another test")
```

The output of the snippet above in `logfile.log` is:

```
test
another test
```

but the output in `stdout` (python interactive console) is:

```
>>> print("test")
2022-05-30 02:13:31,168 test
>>> logger.info("another test")
2022-05-30 02:13:38,081 another test
```

Why isn't the `logger` writing the formatted date in `logfile.log` but in `stdout`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13733552/logger-configuration-to-log-to-file-and-print-to-stdout

Comment: every handler may use different format and you have to set it manually.

Comment: By default, `basicConfig()` only creates a stream handler.

Answer (score 0):

After trying around for a bit, I found

```py
import logging

# this is a hack to log print statements to a file
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format="%(asctime)s %(message)s",
handlers=[
        logging.StreamHandler(),
        logging.FileHandler("logfile.log", "a"),
    ],)
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.propagate = False
print = logger.info

# testing it:
print("test")
logger.info("another test")
```

to work exactly as i want.
The output in `logfile.log` is now:

```
2022-05-30 19:44:02,354 test
2022-05-30 19:44:02,355 another test
```