# Making Python loggers output all messages to stdout in addition to log file

Tags: python, logging, error-logging, python-logging

Is there a way to make Python logging using the `logging` module automatically output things to stdout *in addition* to the log file where they are supposed to go? For example, I'd like all calls to `logger.warning`, `logger.critical`, `logger.error` to go to their intended places but in addition always be copied to `stdout`. This is to avoid duplicating messages like:

```
mylogger.critical("something failed")
print("something failed")
```

Comment: Please check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9321741/printing-to-screen-and-writing-to-a-file-at-the-same-time

Answer (score 924, accepted):

All logging output is handled by the handlers; just add a [`logging.StreamHandler()`](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.handlers.html#streamhandler) to the root logger.

Here's an example configuring a stream handler (using `stdout` instead of the default `stderr`) and adding it to the root logger:

```
import logging
import sys

root = logging.getLogger()
root.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
root.addHandler(handler)
```

Comment: That's fine but if it's already redirected to a file how can I have it be printed to ``stdout`` in addition?

Comment: @user248237: By adding a *new* handler as illustrated. New handlers do not replace the existing handlers, they *also* get to process the log entries.

Comment: @MartijnPieters is there a way to add a string to every log statement printed out?

Comment: @PrakharMohanSrivastava I'd guess you can just add it to the string passed into `logging.Formatter`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Why setLevel is done multiple times both in StreamHandler and at root level?

Comment: @himanshu219: the logger has a level, and the handler has a level. The logger will handle messages of that level and higher, and the handler will handle messages of that level and higher. It lets you differentiate between different loggers and different handlers.

Comment: @MartijnPieters my point was what is the use case here? If we have a single handler wouldn't it be sufficient to set level only in root logger. Also another point is even if one has multiple handlers wouldn't it makes sense to set level only at handler level not at logger level.The only use case I think is that setting level at logger level sets the default level for those handlers which do not set any level.

Comment: @himanshu219: the use case is that as soon as you start adding multiple handlers, you usually want to differentiate. DEBUG to the console, WARNING and up to a file, etc.

Comment: Do you need to do `root = logging.getLogger()` if you use `logging.basicConfig()`?

Comment: @Lou: if you can get the desired logging configuration set up with `logging.basicConfig()`, then no, you don't need to fetch a reference to the root logger.

Comment: how about catching subprocess log calls back to the parent process as variables?

Comment: @VaidøtasI. that's well outside the scope of this question/answer pair, and depends on a lot of factors.

Comment: Hi, great answer, but seeing it's been 5 years since updated, is it better now to do it [differently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46098711/19674402)?

Comment: @PythonForEver: if you already have a configured root logger, then `basicConfig()` will not touch the handlers on it (unless you set `force=True`, and then it'll replace _all_ handlers).

Answer (score 817):

The simplest way to log to stdout using [`basicConfig`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig):

```
import logging
import sys

logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stdout, level=logging.DEBUG)
```

Comment: Hm, but this isn't logged to a file, right? The question was how to do logging to file _and_ to console.

Comment: Ref link: [Python3 Docs: Logging.basicConfig](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig)

Comment: In Python 3 at least, it looks like omitting `stream=sys.stdout` still works for logging to the console for me.

Comment: @TaylorEdmiston Yeah, but it's the stderr stream AFAIK. Try redirecting the output from the shell.

Comment: OK. This doesn't answer both: logging to file and to console, but it was nice to find what I needed in 3 lines or less.

Comment: it's a bit late & i'm not professional at logging, but i think we could get anything into a file using `with open('logfile.txt', 'a+', encoding='utf-8') as f:` then do `print(logging ..., file=f)`

Comment: @Sorin can confirm it would stream to stdout.

Comment: Can't believe i almost paid for datadog when i needed one line

Answer (score 156):

You could create two handlers for file and stdout and then create one logger with `handlers` argument to [`basicConfig`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig). It could be useful if you have the same log_level and format output for both handlers:

```
import logging
import sys

file_handler = logging.FileHandler(filename='tmp.log')
stdout_handler = logging.StreamHandler(stream=sys.stdout)
handlers = [file_handler, stdout_handler]

logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.DEBUG, 
    format='[%(asctime)s] {%(filename)s:%(lineno)d} %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
    handlers=handlers
)

logger = logging.getLogger('LOGGER_NAME')
```

Answer (score 84):

It's possible using multiple handlers.

```
import logging
import auxiliary_module

# create logger with 'spam_application'
log = logging.getLogger('spam_application')
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# create formatter and add it to the handlers
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

# create file handler which logs even debug messages
fh = logging.FileHandler('spam.log')
fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
fh.setFormatter(formatter)
log.addHandler(fh)

# create console handler with a higher log level
ch = logging.StreamHandler()
ch.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
ch.setFormatter(formatter)
log.addHandler(ch)

log.info('creating an instance of auxiliary_module.Auxiliary')
a = auxiliary_module.Auxiliary()
log.info('created an instance of auxiliary_module.Auxiliary')

log.info('calling auxiliary_module.Auxiliary.do_something')
a.do_something()
log.info('finished auxiliary_module.Auxiliary.do_something')

log.info('calling auxiliary_module.some_function()')
auxiliary_module.some_function()
log.info('done with auxiliary_module.some_function()')

# remember to close the handlers
for handler in log.handlers:
    handler.close()
    log.removeFilter(handler)
```

Please see: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html

Comment: Wonderful answer, albeit a bit messy. Love how you show how to use different levels and formats for streams and files. +1, but +2 in spirit.

Comment: For me this did not work without the `sys.stdout` parameter in `ch = logging.StreamHandler()`

Answer (score 45):

Here is a solution based on the powerful but poorly documented [`logging.config.dictConfig` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.config.html#logging.config.dictConfig).
Instead of sending every log message to `stdout`, it sends messages with log level `ERROR` and higher to `stderr` and everything else to `stdout`.
This can be useful if other parts of the system are listening to `stderr` or `stdout`.

```
import logging
import logging.config
import sys

class _ExcludeErrorsFilter(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, record):
        """Only lets through log messages with log level below ERROR ."""
        return record.levelno < logging.ERROR


config = {
    'version': 1,
    'filters': {
        'exclude_errors': {
            '()': _ExcludeErrorsFilter
        }
    },
    'formatters': {
        # Modify log message format here or replace with your custom formatter class
        'my_formatter': {
            'format': '(%(process)d) %(asctime)s %(name)s (line %(lineno)s) | %(levelname)s %(message)s'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console_stderr': {
            # Sends log messages with log level ERROR or higher to stderr
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'formatter': 'my_formatter',
            'stream': sys.stderr
        },
        'console_stdout': {
            # Sends log messages with log level lower than ERROR to stdout
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'formatter': 'my_formatter',
            'filters': ['exclude_errors'],
            'stream': sys.stdout
        },
        'file': {
            # Sends all log messages to a file
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'formatter': 'my_formatter',
            'filename': 'my.log',
            'encoding': 'utf8'
        }
    },
    'root': {
        # In general, this should be kept at 'NOTSET'.
        # Otherwise it would interfere with the log levels set for each handler.
        'level': 'NOTSET',
        'handlers': ['console_stderr', 'console_stdout', 'file']
    },
}

logging.config.dictConfig(config)
```

Comment: had to rename the logger to an empty string to actually get the root logger.  Otherwise very helpful, thanks !

Comment: whoa, never realized the existence of `dictConfig` before!! much gratitude!!!

Comment: up for dictConfig usage which allows loading logging from a config file more easily

Comment: @rkachach the idea of storing logger config in a yaml file seems more robust as it allows code reusage

Comment: This is how django logging is setup, it allows for some finegrained and powerful logging configurations...

Answer (score 39):

The simplest way to log to file and to stderr:

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename="logfile.txt")
stderrLogger=logging.StreamHandler()
stderrLogger.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(logging.BASIC_FORMAT))
logging.getLogger().addHandler(stderrLogger)
```

Comment: This doesn't show labels INFO, DEBUG, and ERROR before the logging message in the console. It does show those labels in the file. Any ideas to also show the labels in the console ?

Comment: @JahMyst you have to change the `format` parameter of `root` logger's formatter

Answer (score 32):

For more detailed explanations - great documentation at that [link](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html).
For example: It's easy, you only need to set up two loggers.

```py
import sys
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger('')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
fh = logging.FileHandler('my_log_info.log')
sh = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
formatter = logging.Formatter('[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s [%(filename)s.%(funcName)s:%(lineno)d] %(message)s', datefmt='%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S')
fh.setFormatter(formatter)
sh.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(fh)
logger.addHandler(sh)

def hello_logger():
    logger.info("Hello info")
    logger.critical("Hello critical")
    logger.warning("Hello warning")
    logger.debug("Hello debug")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(hello_logger())
```

Output - terminal:

```sh
[Mon, 10 Aug 2020 12:44:25] INFO [TestLoger.py.hello_logger:15] Hello info
[Mon, 10 Aug 2020 12:44:25] CRITICAL [TestLoger.py.hello_logger:16] Hello critical
[Mon, 10 Aug 2020 12:44:25] WARNING [TestLoger.py.hello_logger:17] Hello warning
[Mon, 10 Aug 2020 12:44:25] DEBUG [TestLoger.py.hello_logger:18] Hello debug
None
```

Output - in file:

[image: log in file]

---

#### UPDATE: color terminal

Package:

```sh
pip install colorlog
```

Code:

```py
import sys
import logging
import colorlog

logger = logging.getLogger('')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
fh = logging.FileHandler('my_log_info.log')
sh = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
formatter = logging.Formatter('[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s [%(filename)s.%(funcName)s:%(lineno)d] %(message)s', datefmt='%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S')
fh.setFormatter(formatter)
sh.setFormatter(colorlog.ColoredFormatter('%(log_color)s [%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s [%(filename)s.%(funcName)s:%(lineno)d] %(message)s', datefmt='%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S'))
logger.addHandler(fh)
logger.addHandler(sh)

def hello_logger():
    logger.info("Hello info")
    logger.critical("Hello critical")
    logger.warning("Hello warning")
    logger.debug("Hello debug")
    logger.error("Error message")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    hello_logger()
```

output:
[image]

#### Recommendation:

[Complete logger configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38537905/set-logging-levels/65975273#65975273) from `INI` file, which also includes setup for `stdout` and `debug.log`:

- `handler_file`

  - `level=WARNING`
- `handler_screen`

  - `level=DEBUG`

Answer (score 17):

Since no one has shared a neat two liner, I will share my own:

```
logging.basicConfig(filename='logs.log', level=logging.DEBUG, format="%(asctime)s:%(levelname)s: %(message)s")
logging.getLogger().addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an extremely simple example:

```
import logging
l = logging.getLogger("test")

# Add a file logger
f = logging.FileHandler("test.log")
l.addHandler(f)

# Add a stream logger
s = logging.StreamHandler()
l.addHandler(s)

# Send a test message to both -- critical will always log
l.critical("test msg")
```

The output will show "test msg" on stdout and also in the file.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `tee`. Configure the app to write to stdout, and run

```bash
python3 app.py | tee log.txt
```

Then you'll get the log messages in your stdout as well as in log.txt.

Comment: This is super underrated. Does the job. Nothing less nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

I simplified my source code (whose original version is OOP and uses a configuration file), to give you an alternative solution to @EliasStrehle's one, without using the dictConfig (thus easiest to integrate with existing source code):

```
import logging
import sys


def create_stream_handler(stream, formatter, level, message_filter=None):
    handler = logging.StreamHandler(stream=stream)
    handler.setLevel(level)
    handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    if message_filter:
        handler.addFilter(message_filter)
    return handler


def configure_logger(logger: logging.Logger, enable_console: bool = True, enable_file: bool = True):
    if not logger.handlers:
        if enable_console:
            message_format: str = '{asctime:20} {name:16} {levelname:8} {message}'
            date_format: str = '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S'
            level: int = logging.DEBUG
            formatter = logging.Formatter(message_format, date_format, '{')

            # Configures error output (from Warning levels).
            error_output_handler = create_stream_handler(sys.stderr, formatter,
                                                         max(level, logging.WARNING))
            logger.addHandler(error_output_handler)

            # Configures standard output (from configured Level, if lower than Warning,
            #  and excluding everything from Warning and higher).
            if level < logging.WARNING:
                standard_output_filter = lambda record: record.levelno < logging.WARNING
                standard_output_handler = create_stream_handler(sys.stdout, formatter, level,
                                                                standard_output_filter)
                logger.addHandler(standard_output_handler)

        if enable_file:
            message_format: str = '{asctime:20} {name:16} {levelname:8} {message}'
            date_format: str = '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S'
            level: int = logging.DEBUG
            output_file: str = '/tmp/so_test.log'

            handler = logging.FileHandler(output_file)
            formatter = logging.Formatter(message_format, date_format, '{')
            handler.setLevel(level)
            handler.setFormatter(formatter)
            logger.addHandler(handler)
```

This is a very simple way to test it:

```
logger: logging.Logger = logging.getLogger('MyLogger')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
configure_logger(logger, True, True)
logger.debug('Debug message ...')
logger.info('Info message ...')
logger.warning('Warning ...')
logger.error('Error ...')
logger.fatal('Fatal message ...')
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case a module I was importing was messing with the configuration.

The following code was enough to force my own config:

```py
for handler in logging.root.handlers:
    logging.root.removeHandler(handler)
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logging.info("test")
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple but explicit way:

```py
import logging
import sys

logger: Logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

logger.addHandler(logging.FileHandler(f"{__name__}.log"))
logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout))
```