# Logging all errors and stdout output with Python

Tags: python, linux, logging

I know this has been discussed here before, but I haven't found a solution that will work for me.  I already have a python script that I wrote, and I currently have it run at boot.  What I would like to do is log all outputs, which include any print statements to the console, or any error messages that would come up.  I do like the [Logging](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) module, and would prefer to use that over looking at all outputs on the console.  Any suggestions?

Comment: The answer here may be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14058453/making-python-loggers-output-all-messages-to-stdout-in-addition-to-log

Comment: Thank you Matthew, this is actually pretty useful.  However, I'm still a little confused on where the log file for this is located.

Answer (score 0):

If you manage your script using [supervisor](http://supervisord.org/) it will automatically handle all logging of stdout/stderr for you.

Additionally, it can automatically restart your script if it were to crash

Comment: How would I be able to find out if my system is using Supervisor? Also, where I be able to find the log file?

Comment: @user2125538 your system is not using supervisor unless you install it, and configure it, in your supervisor configuration file you get to choose the location of the error logs and the output logs