# PyCharm logging output colours

Tags: python, google-app-engine, logging, pycharm, python-logging

I'm using PyCharm to develop a GAE app in Mac OS X. Is there any way to display colours in the run console of PyCharm?

I've set a [handler](http://xsnippet.org/359377/) to output colours in ansi format. Then, I've added the handler:

```
LOG = logging.getLogger()
LOG.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
for handler in LOG.handlers:
    LOG.removeHandler(handler)

LOG.addHandler(ColorHandler())

LOG.info('hello!')
LOG.warning('hello!')
LOG.debug('hello!')
LOG.error('hello!')
```

But the colour is the same.

[image: PyCharm run console output]

EDIT:

A response from JetBrains [issue tracker](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-11543): Change line 55 of the snippet from sys.stderr to sys.stdout. stderr stream is always colored with red color while stdout not.

Now colours are properly displayed.

Comment: What kind of PyCharm and what version is it?

Comment: PyCharm Pro v3.0.2 for Mac OS X

Comment: The snippet referrenced went offline (as did `xsnippet.org` maybe?) - could you explain where you changed `sys.stderr` to `sys.stdout`?

Comment: In the handler definition of your logging conf you can also simply add `'stream': sys.stdout` to achieve this

Comment: See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45534743/1398841)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

PyCharm doesn't support that feature natively, however you can download the [Grep Console plugin](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7125?pr=pycharm) and set the colors as you like.

Here's a screenshot:
<strike>http://plugins.jetbrains.com/files/7125/screenshot_14104.png</strike> (link is dead)

I hope it helps somewhat :) although it doesn't provide fully colorized console, but it's a step towards it.

Comment: This plugin is great! Just what I was looking for. I really like the "Filter out" option as well.

Comment: Plugin IS awesome. Solved this for me.

Answer (score 82):

As of at least PyCharm 2017.2 you can do this by enabling:

Run | Edit Configurations... | Configuration | Emulate terminal in output console

[image: Run configuration]

[image]

Comment: I was using the [`coloredlogs`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/coloredlogs) package in this screenshot.

Comment: Note that the indicated checkbox only shows if you have "Python" selected in the list view. Other run types do not have this option.

Comment: Not available in pycharm 2020

Comment: @vozman I have pycharm 2020 and it is there, just not displayed exactly the same as in the screenshot.

Comment: Can you please share where is it available now?

Comment: Never mind, figured it out. This feature is only available for local interpreter. I'm using a remote one

Comment: I see this in Pycharm 2020.3.3. Interestingly, turning it on, running my script, then turning it off allowed me to debug with the console while still having colored output. Very useful.

Answer (score 22):

Late to the party, but anyone else with this issue, here's the solution that worked for me:

```
import logging
import sys
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stdout, level=logging.DEBUG)
```

This came from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14058453/making-python-loggers-output-all-messages-to-stdout-in-addition-to-log#28194953)

Answer (score 19):

**Sept. 2019**: PyCharm Community 2019.1

PyCharm colored **all the logs** including info/debug in **red**.

The upshot is: it is not a PyCharm problem, this is how the default `logging` is configured.
Everything written to `sys.stderr` is colored **red** by PyCharm.
When using `StreamHandler()` without arguments, the default stream is `sys.stderr`.

For getting non-colored logs back, specify `logging.StreamHandler(stream=sys.stdout)` in basic config like this:

```
logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.DEBUG,
    format='[%(levelname)8s]:  %(message)s',
    handlers=[
        logging.FileHandler(f'{os.path.basename(__file__)}.log'),
        logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout),
    ])
```

or be more verbose:

```
logging.getLogger().addHandler(logging.StreamHandler(stream=sys.stdout))
```

This fixed my **red** PyCharm logs.

Answer (score 4):

What solved it for me (on PyCharm 2017.2) was going to `Preferences -> Editor -> Color Scheme -> Console Colors` and changing the color of `Console -> Error output`. Of course this also changes the error color but at least you don't see red all the time...

Answer (score 3):

**PyCharm 2019.1.1** (Windows 10, 1709) - runned [snippet](https://xsnippet.org/359377/) as is - works correctly.

[image]

**Bug**: *setFormatter* - does not work.

**Fix**: make change in line 67 and get rid on line 70-71 (unformatted handler adding).

```
self.stream.write(record.msg + "\n", color)
```

to

```
self.stream.write(self.format(record) + "\n", color)
```

Line 70-71 can be moved under manual file run construction for save test ability:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    logging.getLogger().addHandler(ColorHandler())

    logging.debug("Some debugging output")
    logging.info("Some info output")
    logging.error("Some error output")
    logging.warning("Some warning output")
```

**Compared it with standard StreamHandler:**

```
import logging
import logging_colored

log_format = logging.Formatter("[%(threadName)-15.15s] [%(levelname)-5.5s]  %(message)s")
logger = logging.getLogger('Main')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

console = logging.StreamHandler()
console.setFormatter(log_format)
logger.addHandler(console)

console = logging_colored.ColorHandler()
console.setFormatter(log_format)
logger.addHandler(console)
...
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the following solution. Apparently Pycharm redirects sys.stdout. From the [sys module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html):

```
sys.__stdin__
sys.__stdout__
sys.__stderr__
```

> These objects contain the original values of stdin, stderr and stdout
>   at the start of the program. They are used during finalization, and
>   could be useful to print to the actual standard stream no matter if
>   the sys.std* object has been redirected.
>
> It can also be used to restore the actual files to known working file
>   objects in case they have been overwritten with a broken object.
>   However, the preferred way to do this is to explicitly save the
>   previous stream before replacing it, and restore the saved object.

Therefore, to solve this issue you can redirect output to `sys.__stdout__`. Example configuration from my log_config.yml:

```
console:
  class: logging.StreamHandler
  level: DEBUG
  stream: "ext://sys.__stdout__"
  formatter: colorFormatter
```

Answer (score 0):

Grep Console Plugin can config any colour for any pattern text by your requirement, such as this simple one:

The Scrapy output plain text is Red in the original colour, add this rule, and all changes to the default grey colour.

[image]