# How can I get coloredlogs in PyCharm Python Console to format properly?

Tags: python, logging, pycharm

My logging setup is:

```
import coloredlogs
import logging
import sys

# Create a logger object.
# logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

# By default the install() function installs a handler on the root logger,
# this means that log messages from your code and log messages from the
# libraries that you use will all show up on the terminal.
coloredlogs.install(level='DEBUG')



logging.basicConfig(
    format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s',
    level=logging.INFO,
    stream=sys.stdout,
    datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

If I configure the console to use python for output, all lines start at column 0, but all output is red. But if I specify use terminal, the colors are there, but the lines don't start at column 1. They all start with the end column of the line before.

How can I get all log messages starting at column 0 AND in color?

Comment: Any chance you can share a screenshot?  It sounds like each log line is missing a newline char?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PyCharm logging output colours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20333674/pycharm-logging-output-colours)

Comment: @blues it doesn't respect logger.format or logger.datefmt

Comment: @MarcelWilson I tried adding \n, no luck

Comment: Can you show us what it looks like?  It's not entirely clear to me what is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `isatty` to your call to `install`.  This overrides the whatever auto-detection is doing to attempt at determining what type of terminal is being used.

```py
import coloredlogs
import logging
import sys

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
coloredlogs.install(level=logging.DEBUG, logger=logger, isatty=True,
                    fmt="%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s",
                    stream=sys.stdout,
                    datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

logger.debug("this is a debugging message")
logger.info("this is an informational message")
logger.warning("this is a warning message")
logger.error("this is an error message")
logger.critical("this is a critical message")
```

[image]

**explanation:**

If I understood the problem correctly, you are seeing the logging handler default to using `sys.stderr` instead of `sys.stdout`.  (this is why the text would appear in red)

There are likely two issues going on.

1. `coloredlogs.install` needs to be told what type of rules you want in the handler, not `logging.basicConfig`.
2. The automatic terminal detection would fail unless you either force the formatter to think it's a terminal or you set pycharm to 'simulate' a terminal. Fixed by passing in `stream=sys.stdout`

Comment: Thanks you precisely guessed what it was. Sorry for no screenshots. Great answer.