# Python script ran from Bash Script not logging

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, logging

I have a bash script that runs among other things a python script every time the system is booted.

Part of that python script is supposed to be logging to a log file (mostly used for debug purposes).  The script runs fine whether I run it manually or through the bash script.

The issue is that when I run it through the bash script the Python script does not create the log file nor log any of the debugging LOGGING commands I have in the script.

I am assuming this is a permission issue within the directory.

I'm calling my script from  /etc/rc.local

```
sudo /home/user/python_scripts/go.sh &
```

Here is the python line in my bash script (go.sh)..

```
#!/bin/sh
python /home/user/python_scripts/go.py
```

Inside of my python code I am logging using the following (which when I run manually places the log file in the python_scripts directory:

```
import logging

daily_log = 'log-' + str(time.strftime("%m-%d-%y")) + '.log'

logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s (%(levelname)s) - %(message)s', datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p', filename=daily_log,level=logging.DEBUG)

logging.debug(' Debug Message - Error 1241')
```

Comment: post the part where you write to the file.

Comment: How is the `bash` script run? Does the Python script write to a specific file, or just to standard error and/or output (which it inherits from the `bash` script, and could be different from when you run the Python manually)?

Comment: updated with more information...

Comment: Have you checked out the ans to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14058453/making-python-loggers-output-all-messages-to-stdout-in-addition-to-log)? Specifically, setting the logger to `logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the whole path to the log file. It will log into the working directory when the script is run.

If you run from /home/user/python_scripts/ it will put the file there.

If you run from /home/ the file will be in your home directory.