# How to configure the log level of a specific logger using log4j in pyspark?

Tags: logging, apache-spark, log4j, pyspark

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25407550/how-do-i-log-from-my-python-spark-script) StackOverflow thread, I know how to obtain and use the log4j logger in pyspark like so:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
sc = SparkContext()
log4jLogger = sc._jvm.org.apache.log4j
LOGGER = log4jLogger.LogManager.getLogger('MYLOGGER')
LOGGER.info("pyspark script logger initialized")
```

Which works fine with the *spark-submit* script.

My question is how to modify the *log4j.properties* file to configure the log level for *this particular* logger or how to configure it dynamically?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are other answers on how to configure log4j via the log4j.properties file, but I haven't seen anyone mention how to do it dynamically, so:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
sc = SparkContext()
log4jLogger = sc._jvm.org.apache.log4j
LOGGER = log4jLogger.LogManager.getLogger('MYLOGGER')

# same call as you'd make in java, just using the py4j methods to do so
LOGGER.setLevel(log4jLogger.Level.WARN)

# will no longer print
LOGGER.info("pyspark script logger initialized")
```