# Connection timeout between dataproc and sql (CPB100 - Lab3b)

Tags: google-cloud-dataproc

I try to run a script from Google CPB100 - Lab3b (train_and_apply.py) with dataproc against SLQ (mysql ddbb) but I get a timeout.

```
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
```

From the dataproc master I can connect with the mysql command line, but no with the python commands from the script. What can I do to diagnostic this issue?

Success

```
$> mysql --host=35.194.7.XXX --user=root --password
```

Timeout

```
$> pyspark

%> jdbcDriver='com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'
%> jdbcUrl='jdbc:mysql://35.194.7.XXX:3306/recommendation_spark?user=root&password=XXXX'
%> dfRates = sqlContext.read.format('jdbc').options(driver=jdbcDriver, url=jdbcUrl, dbtable='Rating').load()
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what is wrong based on your question, but I would recommend editing the log4j config as described in [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41740750/how-to-configure-the-log-level-of-a-specific-logger-using-log4j-in-pyspark) to see if there are important info or debug logs under com.mysql or org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc.

Comment: Hi Patrick, putting a higher log level doesn't help me. I get more verbosity with the cluster part 'org.apache.hadoop' but the same on the sql part 'com.mysql.jdbc' that raises the error. [Code added in the script "sc.setLogLevel("ALL")"]                     Thanks anyway,