# AWS EMR Spark Python Logging

Tags: python, apache-spark, emr

I'm running a very simple Spark job on AWS EMR and can't seem to get any log output from my script.

I've tried with printing to stderr:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sc = SparkContext(appName="HelloWorld")
    print('Hello, world!', file=sys.stderr)
    sc.stop()
```

And using the spark logger as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34683626/3645881):

```
from pyspark import SparkContext

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sc = SparkContext(appName="HelloWorld")

    log4jLogger = sc._jvm.org.apache.log4j
    logger = log4jLogger.LogManager.getLogger(__name__)
    logger.error('Hello, world!')

    sc.stop()
```

EMR gives me two log files after the job runs: `controller` and `stderr`. Neither log contains the `"Hello, world!"` string. It's my understanding the `stdout` is redirected to `stderr` in spark. The `stderr` log shows that the job is accepted, run, and completed successfully.

So my question is, where can I view my script's log output? Or what should I change in my script to log correctly?

Edit: I used this command to submit the step:

```
aws emr add-steps --region us-west-2 --cluster-id x-XXXXXXXXXXXXX --steps Type=spark,Name=HelloWorld,Args=[--deploy-mode,cluster,--master,yarn,--conf,spark.yarn.submit.waitAppCompletion=true,s3a://path/to/simplejob.py],ActionOnFailure=CONTINUE
```

Comment: What parameters did you submit the job to EMR with?

Comment: I've found that logging for particular steps almost never winds up in the controller or stderr logs that the EMR console pulls alongside the step. Usually I find what I want in the job's container logs (and usually it's in stdout). They're typically at a path like `s3://mybucket/logs/emr/spark/j-XXXXXX/containers/application_XXXXXXXXX/container_XXXXXXX/...`

Comment: @GregReda I found the logs there. Thank you! If you post it as the answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Great! Glad all my time debugging EMR + PySpark hasn't been for nothing :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I've found that EMR's logging for particular steps almost never winds up in the controller or stderr logs that get pulled alongside the step in the AWS console.

Usually I find what I want in the *job's* container logs (and usually it's in stdout).

These are typically at a path like `s3://mybucket/logs/emr/spark/j-XXXXXX/containers/application‌​_XXXXXXXXX/container‌​_XXXXXXX/...`. You might need to poke around within the various `application_...` and `container_...` directories within `containers`.

That last container directory should have a `stdout.log` and `stderr.log`.

Comment: Where do I define/set/find the bucket where the logs are persisted?

Comment: @Dror or anyone else who wants to know, you can set this in the Log_URI EMR config attribute in the JSON.

Comment: If you're debugging the cause of an application failure, once you've found the location of the logs for your application, go to the first directory in the list and look at `stdout.gz`. This is because the driver is the first container to be created.

Answer (score 2):

For what it worth. Let `j-XXX` be the ID of the EMR cluster and assume it is configured to use `logs_bucket` for persisting logs on S3. If you want to find the logs emitted by your code do the following:

1. In AWS console, find the step which you want to review
2. Go to is `stderr` and search for `application_`. Take a note of the full name you find, it should be something like `application_15489xx175355_0yy5`.
3. Go to `s3://logs_bucket/j-XXX/containers` and find the folder `application_15489xx175355_0yy5`.
4. In this folder, you will find at least one folder named `application_15489xx175355_0yy5_ww_vvvv`. In these folders you will find files named `stderr.gz` which contain the logs emitted by your code.

Comment: sir can you please tell me how to store the custom logs to s3 from EMR cluster now i'm able to get all the system logs to s3 bucket but i have a log file which stores all my program logs that's i'm not able to find in s3 bucket but i'm able on EMR which store in this path :/mnt/var/log/hadoop/steps/N please give me a suggestion how to achieve this...thnx in advance

Comment: I wish I knew the answer... Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using emr-5.30.1 running in YARN client mode and got this working using the Python `logging` library.

I didn't like solutions which used the JVM private methods in Spark. Apart from being a private method these caused my application logs to appear in the Spark logs (which are already quite verbose) and furthermore force me to use Spark's logging format.

Sample code using `logging`:

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(
    format="""%(asctime)s,%(msecs)d %(levelname)-8s[%(filename)s:%(funcName)s:%(lineno)d] %(message)s""",
    datefmt="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",
    level=logging.INFO,
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.info('test')
    ...
```

When the cluster is created, I specify `LogUri='s3://mybucket/emr/'` via the console / CLI / boto.

Log output appears in `stdout.gz` of the relevant step, which can be found using either of the below options.

1. In the EMR Console choose your Cluster. On the "Summary" tab, click the tiny folder icon next to "Log URI". Within the popup, navigate to steps, choose your step id, and open `stdout.gz`
2. In S3 navigate to the logs directly. They are located at `emr/j-<cluster-id>/steps/s-<step-id>/stdout.gz` in `mybucket`.

Answer (score 0):

To capture the output of the script you can try something like below as well

```
/usr/bin/spark-submit --master yarn --num-executors 300 myjob.py param1 > s3://databucket/log.out 2>&1 &
```

This will write the script output into a log file at s3 location.