# How to find the stderr/stdout log for the bootstrap action of EMR

Tags: amazon-emr

I have a EMR cluster created with a bootstrap action (B.A) and the console shows there are errors for the B.A.

Is there any way I could check the stderr/stdout for the B.A just like the normal steps?

Comment: if your cluster is terminated, and then you want to see the log file, you can follow these steps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67069405/how-to-see-output-from-executors-on-amazon-emr/67075154#67075154 
This will have all the log including the log of bootstrap actions.

Answer (score 1):

They are located at `/mnt/var/log/bootstrap-actions` on EMR master node. You can check these [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-manage-view-web-log-files.html) for where other logs are located. As a side note, the logs are being continuously written to while EMR cluster is being initialized so you can `tail -f` them.