# Writing log with python logging module in databricks to azure datalake not working

Tags: python, azure, logging, azure-data-lake, azure-databricks

I'm trying to write my own log files to Azure Datalake Gen 2 in a Python-Notebook within Databricks. I'm trying to achieve that by using the Python logging module.

Unfortunately I can't get it working. No errors are raised, the folders are created but no file with logging content is created. Even if the files exists, nothing is written to it.

A local python script works just fine, but I can't get it working in Databricks.

Here is my code:

```py
# mount
if not any(mount.mountPoint == '/mnt/log' for mount in dbutils.fs.mounts()):
  dbutils.fs.mount(
    source = "abfss://log@datalake.dfs.core.windows.net/",
    mount_point = "/mnt/log",
    extra_configs = configs)

# vars
folder_log = '/mnt/log/test/2019'
file_log = '201904.log'

# add folder if not existent
dbutils.fs.mkdirs(folder_log)

# setup logging
import logging
logging.basicConfig(
  filename=folder_log+'/'+file_log,
  format='%(asctime)s | %(name)s | %(levelname)s | %(message)s',
  datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S UTC (%z)',
  level=logging.NOTSET
)

# test
logging.info('Hello World.')
```

Mounting seems to be ok.

Adding and writing files with dbutils works fine:

`dbutils.fs.put(folder_log+'/'+file_log, 'Hello World.')`

Writing to file like that works fine too:

```
f = open('/dbfs/mnt/log/test/2019/201904.log', 'w+')
f.write("This is line %d\r\n")
f.close()
```

Also tried adding "dbfs" to path

```
filename='/dbfs'+folder_log+'/'+file_log,
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Any updates to this problem?

Comment: Databricks appears to do something strange to the builtin python logging module and getLogger. I've had to hook into log4j via py4j based on the solution in https://stackoverflow.com/a/34683626/1789708

Comment: I would recommend the link posted by @ScottH for anyone not on Azure.

Answer (score 6):

You can use azure_storage_logging handler:

```
import logging
from azure_storage_logging.handlers import BlobStorageRotatingFileHandler
log = logging.getLogger('service_logger')
azure_blob_handler = BlobStorageRotatingFileHandler(filename, 
                                                    account_name,
                                                    account_key,
                                                    maxBytes,
                                                    container)
log.addHandler(azure_blob_handler)
```

Comment: It seems like this azure_storage_logging module is no longer being maintained has some outstanding issues.

Comment: this gives me an error, Operation not supported when running it for the second time and after

Answer (score -2):

Let me explain the steps for accessing or performing Write operations on Azure data lake storage using python

1) Register an application in Azure AD

[image]

[image]

2) Grant permission in data lake for the application you have registered

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

3) Please get the client secret from azure AD for the application you have registered.

4) You need to write a code to mount the directory in Azure data lake like below

```
dbutils.fs.mkdirs("/mnt/mountdatalake")

config = {"dfs.adls.oauth2.access.token.provider.type": "ClientCredential",
           "dfs.adls.oauth2.client.id": "Registered_Client_Id_From_Azure_Portal",
             "dfs.adls.oauth2.credential": "Cleint_Secret_Obtained_By_Azure_Portal",
               "dfs.adls.oauth2.refresh.url":"https://login.microsoftonline.com/Your_Directory_ID/oauth2/token"}

dbutils.fs.amount(
               source="adl://mydata.azuredatalakestore.net/mountdatabricks",
               mount_point ="/mnt/mountdatalake",
extra_configs=configs)
```

Once the configuration/mounting is done using application client credential, you are good to access the directory and log it.

for example , Below I have extracted couple of records from SQL server and stored it in azure data lake

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am using Data Lake Storage Gen2 (which was merged with a storage account), so the connection and mounting looks a little bit different than your suggestion for Data Lake Storage Gen1.

An app is registered and access is given by App ID / Object ID and Service Principal ID.

The connection generally seems not to be the problem, because reading and writing with ```dbutils.fs.put``` or ```f.write()``` works fine. But it doesn't work with python logging module and I don't know why and how this is different from other methods of writing files.