# How to create logging from Python notebook in Databricks to ADLS Gen2 (without mounting)?

Tags: python, azure, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I'm trying to create a logging mechanism inside Databricks Python notebook. Tried using below code to achieve the same -

```
import logging

def create_logger(name,log_path=None):
  
    logger = logging.getLogger(name)  
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    formatter    = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s - %(levelname)-8s - %(message)s")  
    stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    stream_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(stream_handler)
    
    if log_path is not None:        
        file_handler = logging.FileHandler(log_path)
        file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
        logger.addHandler(file_handler)
        
    return logger
```

However, whenever I'm trying to call the function as below -

```
from datetime import date, datetime
current_date = date.today()
current_timestamp = datetime.strftime(datetime.now(),"%Y%m%d%H%M%S")

name = "temp_logs"
log_path = f"abfss://{storageContainer}@{storageAccount}.dfs.core.windows.net/{target_dir}/logs/{current_date}/{name}_{current_timestamp}.txt"

logger = create_logger(name = name,log_path = log_path)
```

This is giving error as -

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: /databricks/driver/abfss:/temp-ontainer@teststorage.dfs.core.windows.net/test/logs/2021-09-13/temp_logs_20210913101150.txt'
```

Is there a way to handle this (without using mount point location) ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Writing log with python logging module in databricks to azure datalake not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55689544/writing-log-with-python-logging-module-in-databricks-to-azure-datalake-not-worki). Just change your FileHandler to BlobStorageRotatingFileHandler

Comment: @Kafels - Getting error as 
`module 'logging' has no attribute 'BlobStorageRotatingFileHandler'`

Answer (score 1):

We can try using “BlobStorageRotatingFileHandler” by importing it as below:

```
from azure_storage_logging.handlers import BlobStorageRotatingFileHandler
```

Can refer to the python document about azure-storage-logging as it provides functionality to send output from the standard Python logging APIs to Microsoft Azure Storage.

[image]

Sample code as below:

```
import logging
from azure_storage_logging.handlers import TableStorageHandler

# configure the handler and add it to the logger
logger = logging.getLogger('example')
handler = TableStorageHandler(account_name='mystorageaccountname',
                              account_key='mystorageaccountkey',
                              extra_properties=('%(hostname)s',
                                                '%(levelname)s'))
logger.addHandler(handler)

# output log messages
logger.info('info message')
logger.warning('warning message')
logger.error('error message')
```

Use the above logs to record the error messages.

And for "directory not found" we need to check the path. Please have a look on the [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/azure-storage-logging/)