# How to send out logs from a UDF function in Pyspark

Tags: logging, pyspark, user-defined-functions

If you add any kind of logging into a UDF function in PySpark, it won't appear anywhere. Is it some kind of method to make this happen?

So far I tried standard python logging, py4j and also print.

We're running PySpark 2.3.2 with YARN cluster manager on AWS EMR clusters.

For example.
Here's a function I want to use:

```py
def parse_data(attr):
    try:
        # execute something
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(e)
        return None
```

I convert it to UDF:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
parse_data_udf = F.udf(parse_data, StringType())
```

And I will use it on a dataframe:

```py
from pyspark.sql import types as pst
dataframe = dataframe.withColumn("new_column", parse_data_udf("column").cast(pst.StringType())
```

The logs from the function will NOT appear anywhere.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25407550/how-do-i-log-from-my-python-spark-script

Comment: Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40806225/pyspark-logging-from-the-executor

Comment: Both of these are about general logging, my question is about, logs inside of a UDF.

Comment: @Mariusz - Sorry, we tried that. It didn't work.

Comment: Hi did you come up with any solution, im stuck at same point

Comment: i'm checking similar issue .. the output of the print statements in udf are in the stderr

Answer (score 0):

When using yarn you can use the following YARN CLI command to check the container logs.

This is where the stdout/stderr (and thus what you log inside the udf) is probably located.

```
yarn logs -applicationId <Application ID> -containerId <Container ID>
```