# Include print statements in log file

Tags: python, debugging, logging, diagnostics

I'm trying to migrate from elaborate, `if(debug):` flagged, print statements for debugging to using the builtin [`logging` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes).  I really like that I can log output both to a log file, and to `stdout` (for example, [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14058453/making-python-loggers-output-all-messages-to-stdout-in-addition-to-log)).  I'm interested in doing the reverse; **can I include stdout information into the logger?**

Edit:  I **dont** want to "**Redirect**" stdout to the log, I want to **include** it in the log... in **addition** to going to stdout.

---

For example,

```
print "Loading data"
sources = getSources(params)
logging.debug("> From %d sources" % (len(sources)))
data = loadData(sources)

def getSources(params):
    logging.info(">> Using parameters : %s" % (params))
    ...
    return sources
```

Let's say that `logging` is sending to both `stdout` and to a log file.  It's great that "Loading Data" is always printed, and I can choose how much of the next two statements are:

```
Loading Data
> From ___ sources
>> Using parameters : ___
```

But how can I also get "Loading Data" logged to the log file?

---

The two options I've considered are:

1) Writing two statements which is annoying and clumsy:

```
print "Loading Data"
logging.info("Loading Data")
```

or, 2) using `critical` to log for all levels, but this seems abusive...

```
logging.critical("Loading Data")
```

Comment: @MartijnPieters edited to explain

Comment: So the other solution cannot be adapted? Just write to the original `sys.stdout` *as well*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Then I'm in the same position as the (1) attempt I described: duplicating the output statement.  i.e. `print "Loading Data"; sys.stdout.write("Loading Data")`

Comment: No, have the `LogWriter` class log both to the logger *and* write to `sys.stdout` (or rather, to a saved reference to that object, since you'll be replacing `sys.stdout` with the `LogWriter` instance).

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I think that's effectively the solution I linked to in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14058453/making-python-loggers-output-all-messages-to-stdout-in-addition-to-log)... which ties into my attempt (2) ---- which, in deed, might be the only/best solution.