# How to redirect TensorFlow logging to a file?

Tags: logging, tensorflow

I'm using TensorFlow-Slim, which has some useful logging printed out to console by `tf.logging`. I would like to redirect those loggings to a text file, but couldn't find a way doing so. I looked at the `tf_logging.py` source code, which exposes the following, but doesn't seem to have the option to write logs to a file. Please let me know if I missed something.

```
__all__ = ['log', 'debug', 'error', 'fatal', 'info', 'warn', 'warning',
           'DEBUG', 'ERROR', 'FATAL', 'INFO', 'WARN',
           'flush', 'log_every_n', 'log_first_n', 'vlog',
           'TaskLevelStatusMessage', 'get_verbosity', 'set_verbosity']
```

Answer (score 37):

```
import logging

# get TF logger
log = logging.getLogger('tensorflow')
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# create formatter and add it to the handlers
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

# create file handler which logs even debug messages
fh = logging.FileHandler('tensorflow.log')
fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
fh.setFormatter(formatter)
log.addHandler(fh)
```

My solution is inspired by [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14058453/making-python-loggers-output-all-messages-to-stdout-in-addition-to-log).

Comment: Didn't work even with `logging.NOTSET`, `'tensorflow.log'` file is empty.

Comment: I can confirm this doesnt work just like that. Changing or not touching log levels or the formatter does not help. Python 3.8.5 and tf 2.4

Answer (score 6):

You are right, there are no knobs for you to do that.

If you truly, positively, absolutely cannot live with that, `tf.logging` is based on python logging. So,

`import logging
tf.logging._logger.basicConfig(filename='tensorflow.log', level=logging.DEBUG)`

Note that you are on your own on an unsupported path, and that behavior may break at anytime.

You may also file a feature request at our [github issue](https://www.github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues) page.

Comment: as of TF 1.9 this code generates "AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.tools.api.generator.api.logging' has no attribute '_logger"
'

Comment: Does the top answer work for you? You can now use `logging.getLogger('tensorflow')` to get the logger object.

Comment: no it does not.  While you can get a logger called tensorflow, the format of the TF source itself apparently can't be changed nor can it be redirected to a file.  I think it may be a bug.

Comment: @KevinJohnsrude please file a ticket to our github page and CC drpngx, so that we can have an extended discussion there. Thanks!

Comment: also in TF2.4 Message=module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'logging'

Answer (score 2):

A easy workaround would be to direct the output from command line to a file. For example,

```
python training.py 1> output.log 2> error.log
# 1 for stdout stream and 2 for stderr stream
```

The benefit, in light of the accepted answer, is that you get **ALL the logs**. The reason is that not all the logging comes from python (Remember the runtime is implemented in C++). For instance, you could get very helpful debugging logging (including info about Tensor memory allocation) by setting the environment variable.

```
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_VLOG_LEVEL'] = '3'
```

(Do this with **CAUTION**. The amount of logging is staggering.)

For a glimpse of how logging is implemented in C++,

> https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/platform/default/logging.h
>   https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/platform/default/logging.cc
>
> In particular it looks like logging messages are written to stderr in this line:
>
> https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/platform/default/logging.cc#L73

which I quote from the discussion [here](https://groups.google.com/a/tensorflow.org/forum/#!topic/discuss/SO_JRts-VIs)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using python logging in your project, one of the option will be to define the logger with name "tensorflow" in a logging config file.

Then `_logger = _logging.getLogger('tensorflow')` will use the logger and specified handlers from your config file.