# Custom logging handlers in TensorFlow 1.8

Tags: tensorflow

For previous versions of TensorFlow, we've been overriding handlers of `tf.logging._logger` to get custom logging behavior used in the rest of our python codebase:

- standardized log format
- log at level INFO to stdout and DEBUG to a file
- on GCP, log to Stackdriver with an easy-to-search string prepended

---

For example, on TF 1.7, the following snippet (some logging boilerplate omitted)

```
    import tensorflow as tf
    tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)
    tf_logging = tf.logging._logger
    tf_logging.handlers = [_std_out_handler()]
    tf_logging.propagate = False
    _logging.info("EXPECTED LOG FORMAT")
    tf.logging.info("TF LOG FORMAT")
```

produces

```
[INFO |mrtx] 2018-05-18 15:10:07,613                                            /merantix_core/common/util/logging.py:189  --- EXPECTED LOG FORMAT
[INFO |mrtx] 2018-05-18 15:10:07,614  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/tf_logging.py:116  --- TF LOG FORMAT
```

---

In TF 1.8, `tf.logging._logger` is no longer accessible.  Based on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40559667/how-to-redirect-tensorflow-logging-to-a-file), I tried setting

```
   tf_logging = _logging.getLogger('tensorflow')
```

in the above snippet, but the output is

```
[INFO |mrtx] 2018-05-18 15:20:34,043                                            /merantix_core/common/util/logging.py:190  --- EXPECTED LOG FORMAT
INFO:tensorflow:TF LOG FORMAT
```

---

I don't see any changes to [tf_logging.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.8/tensorflow/python/platform/tf_logging.py) between TF 1.7 and 1.8 .  I assume the tf_export calls weren't being enforced before, but are being enforced now.  Is there still some way to override handlers for `tf.logging`?  Alternatively, is there a more canonical way to get the above functionality?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can still access the tensorflow logger by directly importing the logging module:

```
from tensorflow.python.platform import tf_logging
tf_logger = tf_logging._get_logger()
tf_logger.handlers = handlers
```

Answer (score 2):

The following code is tested well with tensorflow 1.12.0.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger('tensorflow')
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
for h in logger.handlers:
    h.setFormatter(formatter)
tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)
tf.logging.info("testing")
tf.logging.debug("debug mesg")
tf.logging.warning("a warning mesg")
```

When we import tensorflow, there is always a logger name 'tensorflow'. We need to call it and change its format.

`Logger.handlers` contains only one handler.

`tf.logging._get_logger()` does not work in tf 1.12.0.

We can modify the code above to add handlers (steam, file, email, etc) to tensorflow logger.

Comment: it also works in tf1.15