# Pyomo - Streaming model solver output via Websocket with FastAPI

Tags: logging, websocket, fastapi, solver, pyomo

I'm creating an optimization model with `pyomo` and trying to expose it via `FastAPI` (plain `FastAPI` or `celery`). In this process I'm trying to capture the `solver` output to stream it near-real-time to user to inspect it. To stream this data, I'm trying to use `WebSockets`

An example for this app can be as follows:
**Structure**

```
|--main.py
|--model.py
|--template.py
```

### **model.py**

```
import pyomo.environ as pyo

model = pyo.ConcreteModel()

model.t = pyo.RangeSet(10000)
model.x = pyo.Var(model.t, domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals)

def constraint(model):
    return sum(model.x[t] for t in model.t) >= 10


model.c1 = pyo.Constraint(rule=constraint)

model.obj = pyo.Objective(
    expr=sum(model.x[t] for t in model.t),
    sense=pyo.minimize
)
```

### **main.py**

```
import logging

from fastapi import FastAPI, WebSocket
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse
from pyomo.common.tee import capture_output
from pyomo.environ import SolverFactory

from model import instance
from template import template

logger = logging.getLogger(mod_name="simple-example-logger")

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/")
async def get():
    return HTMLResponse(template)


@app.websocket("/ws")
async def websocket_endpoint(websocket: WebSocket):
    await websocket.accept()
    # --- Solve Model ---       
    while True:
        data = await websocket.receive_text()
        await websocket.send_text(f"Optimizing...")
        solver = SolverFactory("cbc")
        # solver.solve(instance, tee=True, logfile="myfile.log")
        print("Loading...")
        with capture_output() as LOGER:
            solver_logger = logging.StreamHandler(LOGER)
            logger.addHandler(solver_logger)
            solver.solve(instance, tee=True)
            text = solver_logger.stream.getvalue()
            print(text)
            replace_string = r"\n"
            await websocket.send_text(f"Message text was: {solver_logger.stream.getvalue().replace(replace_string, '</br>')}")`
```

### **template.py**

This is only an .py file with an string with html data to stream WS

```
template = """
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Chat</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>WebSocket Chat</h1>
        <form action="" onsubmit="sendMessage(event)">
            <input type="text" id="messageText" autocomplete="off"/>
            <button>Send</button>
        </form>
        <ul id='messages'>
        </ul>
        <script>
            var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8000/ws");
            ws.onmessage = function(event) {
                var messages = document.getElementById('messages')
                var message = document.createElement('li')
                var content = document.createTextNode(event.data)
                message.appendChild(content)
                messages.appendChild(message)
            };
            function sendMessage(event) {
                var input = document.getElementById("messageText")
                ws.send(input.value)
                input.value = ''
                event.preventDefault()
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
"""
```

If i run `uvicorn main:app --reload` I'm able to stream the solver log into the template, but this only happen when the solving process had finish. For a much-larger model that takes long to solve, I want to watch the logs as `near-real-time` as possible.

Any hint on this approach?

Comment: You might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71738644/17865804) (and its references) helpful

Comment: Thank you, @Chris Your link help me to find the way to make it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally could handle this. I'm not that sure that this is the best approach,  but this works

Thanks to @Chris for the comment to [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71731924/how-to-avoid-blocking-the-asyncio-event-loop-with-looping-functions/71738644#71738644).

I also used [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49073580/16791187) to achieve this streaming

I decide to "stream" a "batch" of logs to avoid overhead since some solver (*e.g., scip*) generate a lot of verbose while optimizing, Then I stream a batch every 5 seconds.

I generate a class to stream replacing the `sys.stdout`. The method `_write_by_batches` generates a new event loop to allow asynchronously streaming throuth WebSocket generating a new event loop each time that log batch is streamed. Since I want to avoid overhead of streaming each time log

```py
class MyStdOut(TextIOBase):
    def __init__(self, ws: WebSocket, orig_stdout=None,):
        self._ws = ws
        self.orig_stdout = orig_stdout
        self._last_update = datetime.now()
        self._batch = ""
        
    def write(self, s):
        self._stream_solver_log(
            current_time=datetime.now(),
            msg=s
        )
        if self.orig_stdout:
            self.orig_stdout.write(s)

    def _write_by_batches(self, s):
        loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        loop.run_until_complete(
            self._ws.send_text(s)
        )

    def _stream_solver_log(self, current_time: datetime, msg: str):
        if (current_time - self._last_update).total_seconds() >= 5:
            self._write_by_batches(self._batch)
            self._batch = ""
            self._last_update = current_time
        else:
            self._batch = f"{self._batch}\n{msg}"
```

Then in the websocket endpoint, I get the running loop in order to run the `solver.solve(instance, tee=True)` using `loop.run_in_executor`.

The whole `main.py` script is as follows:

**main.py**

```py
from io import TextIOBase
import asyncio
from datetime import datetime
import sys

from fastapi import FastAPI, WebSocket
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse
from pyomo.environ import SolverFactory

from model import instance
from template import template


class MyStdOut(TextIOBase):
    def __init__(self, ws: WebSocket, orig_stdout=None,):
        self._ws = ws
        self.orig_stdout = orig_stdout
        self._last_update = datetime.now()
        self._batch = ""
        
    def write(self, s):
        # new_string = str(s).replace("\n", "/n")
        self._stream_solver_log(
            current_time=datetime.now(),
            msg=s
        )
        if self.orig_stdout:
            self.orig_stdout.write(s)

    def _write_by_batches(self, s):
        loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        loop.run_until_complete(
            self._ws.send_text(s)
        )

    def _stream_solver_log(self, current_time: datetime, msg: str):
        if (current_time - self._last_update).total_seconds() >= 5:
            self._write_by_batches(self._batch)
            self._batch = ""
            self._last_update = current_time
        self._batch = f"{self._batch}\n{msg}"
    
        
def solve_model(solver, model, options):
    return solver.solve(model, **options)


app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/")
async def get():
    return HTMLResponse(template)

@app.websocket("/ws")
async def websocket_endpoint(websocket: WebSocket):
    await websocket.accept()
    # --- Solve Model ---
    solver = SolverFactory("scip")
    original_stdout = sys.stdout  
    sys.stdout = MyStdOut(ws=websocket, orig_stdout=sys.stdout)
    while True:
        data = await websocket.receive_text()
        await websocket.send_text(f"Optimizing...")
        loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
        await asyncio.gather(*[
            loop.run_in_executor(None, solve_model, *[solver, instance, {"tee": True}]),
        ])
        await websocket.send_text(f"{sys.stdout._batch} \n\n\nOptimization finished")
        sys.stdout = original_stdout
```