# How to redirecting print to logging with multiple print arguments?

Tags: python, logging, arguments

I want to redirect the `print()` statements of some arbitrary code to a proper logging functionality.

Unfortunately, the following code works only when `print()` gets a single argument.

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename="logname",
                    filemode='a',
                    format='%(asctime)s,%(msecs)03d %(name)s %(levelname)s %(message)s',
                    datefmt='%D %H:%M:%S',
                    level=logging.DEBUG)

print = logging.debug
print("hallo")
print("makes", "error")
```

This results in the following logfile:

```
03/30/18 14:06:11,881 root DEBUG hallo
```

And the following error in the console:

```
Connected to pydev debugger (build 173.4674.37)
--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 992, in emit
    msg = self.format(record)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 838, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 575, in format
    record.message = record.getMessage()
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 338, in getMessage
    msg = msg % self.args
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
Call stack:
  File "/home/user/install_dir/pycharm/2017-12-12-ultimate-edition/pycharm-2017.3/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1668, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/user/install_dir/pycharm/2017-12-12-ultimate-edition/pycharm-2017.3/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1662, in main
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "/home/user/install_dir/pycharm/2017-12-12-ultimate-edition/pycharm-2017.3/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1072, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "/home/user/install_dir/pycharm/2017-12-12-ultimate-edition/pycharm-2017.3/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "/home/user/PycharmProjects/my_project/attic.py", line 12, in <module>
    print("makes", "error")
Message: 'makes'
Arguments: ('error',)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

How do I have to change the code to make it work for an arbitrary number of arguments of `print()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`print` is no longer itself anymore because you redefined `print` to be `logging.debug`, `debug` only takes the first argument as the message. However, you can define `print` differently, as followed:

```
def print(*args, sep=" ", **kwargs):
    return logging.debug(sep.join(map(lambda x: str(x), args)), **kwargs)
```

This loses the ability to use `debug`'s `*args` to format strings.

> ***`args`*** are the arguments which are merged into `msg` using the string
>   formatting operator. (Note that this means that you can use keywords
>   in the format string, together with a single dictionary argument.)

---

Instead of redefining `print`, I'd advise you use a [StreamHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14058475/6622817).

Comment: Thanks, that was already very helpful. Now I reached the next issue: with your solution, a `dict` cannot be processed. Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Oops, I forgot something important, I believe I fixed it by joining the string representation of all the arguments(this is what the original `print` does), you can try again.