# Output redirection with python

Tags: python, logging

I am trying to run a script and I want its stdout to be redirected to a file. Script is using logging module for logging. When I try to run

```
python verifyPhone.py -f dupl.csv  1> deleted.txt
```

It starts printing output to screen instead of file. But if I replace logger.info with print, I can see outputs in the file.
I am not able to figure out why this is happening.

Does logger does not print to stdout ?
How I can see output on terminal if my stdout is already redirected to file ?

Comment: Use `python verifyPhone.py -f dupl.csv  2> deleted.txt` to redirect stderr.

Comment: I dont want to redirect stderr. Does logging module by default writes to stderr even if i log something at debug or info level ?

Comment: this could be probably useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14058453/making-python-loggers-output-all-messages-to-stdout-in-addition-to-log