# Python shell log command not showing up in docker/kubernetes pod

Tags: python, docker, kubernetes

I ran the following code in the python shell but it is not showing up the docker/kubernetes pod logs:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logging.info("Test")
```

This is a simplified version of what I am trying to do which is essentially run one-off scripts/commands in the python shell and have logs to show up. How do I go about getting this to work? Is it because the shell I opened up is not attached to the process that creates the logs?

I'm currently using Docker and Kubernetes.

Thanks!

Comment: You ran this in a shell? If so then it wont be in the logs. The PID 1 stdout only is sent to logs

Comment: What @TarunLalwani said is 100% true, but you can also cheat and `tee` the output into `/proc/1/fd/1` to have stdout of your process go to the stdout of the container's process (you may have to substitute `/proc/1` for the PID of your container's main process, but it's _usually_ 1); it may be possible to do some `dup2` trickery to get both stdout and stderr to go to `/proc/1`'s fds, but that would require more than 161 more characters :-)

Answer (score 1):

As [Matthew L Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/225016/matthew-l-daniel) wrote, you can cheat by using additional tools as a workaround to send your logs to stdout.

Also, you can import library sys and stream logs to stdout by this lib. There is an example of code:

```
import logging  
import sys  

root = logging.getLogger()  
root.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)  

ch = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)  
ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)  
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')  
ch.setFormatter(formatter)  
root.addHandler(ch)
```

I found it on Stack, so I’ve attached [link as a source.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14058453/making-python-loggers-output-all-messages-to-stdout-in-addition-to-log)