# Making logging module write all logs to only stderr

Tags: python, logging, pytest, stderr

I am using pytest to test a CLI that produces some output.  While running the test, I want to set my CLI's log level to DEBUG.  However, I don't want CLI logs to interfere with tests that are parsing the output of the CLI.

How can I make logging module send all the logs to only stderr?  I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14058453/6862601) post but it talks about sending logs to stderr *in addition to* stdout.

Comment: did you try `logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler(sys.stderr)`?

Comment: (a new comment on purpose) After looking in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.StreamHandler), *stderr* is actually the default of `StreamHandler`s. It will be helpful if you showed how to configure your logger, because according to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig), by simply doing nothing you should get your desired outcome

Comment: `pytest` will capture all output by default; the `capsys` fixture will give you the captured `stdout`/`stderr` output, while `caplog` will capture the log records. I don't think you will get any interference at all. If I'm wrong, give an example of a test where you can't achiveve the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Do the same that the linked answer does but replace stdout with stderr. So you would create a handler with `logging.StreamHandler(sys.stderr)` and make sure this is the only active handler if you want to exclusively have logs go to stderr.

As @Tomerikoo correctly points out you don't need to do anything though as logging defaults to using a StreamHandler with stderr. The only real value of the code below is that it sets a different level than the default. Just `logging.warning('log')` with no other setup will send a log to stderr.

Addendum: you can also achieve this using basicConfig to have less boilerplate code.

```
import logging
import sys
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr, level=logging.INFO)
logging.info('test') # sends log to stderr
```

Comment: Read my comments on the question: interesting thing: *sys.stderr* is actually the default `StreamHandler`, `basicConfig` by default creates the default `StreamHandler`, and `basicConfig` will be automatically called if no handlers defined. So basically this means we can just do `logging.info('test')` and it will go to *stderr*

Answer (score 0):

You can direct the log output for a given logger to stderr as follows.  This defaults to stderr for output, but you can use sys.stdout instead if you prefer.

```
import logging
import sys

DEFAULT_LOGGER_NAME = 'default_logger'


def init_logging(logger_name=DEFAULT_LOGGER_NAME,
                 log_level=logging.DEBUG,
                 stream=None):
    # logging
    logger = logging.getLogger(logger_name)
    logger.setLevel(log_level)
    # create formatter
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
    # create console handler and set level to debug
    if stream is None:
        stream = sys.stderr
    ch = logging.StreamHandler(stream=stream)
    ch.setLevel(log_level)
    # add formatter to ch
    ch.setFormatter(formatter)
    # add ch to logger
    logger.addHandler(ch)

    return logger
```

This function needs to be called at the beginning of your program (e.g. beginning of **main**()).

Then within the code, you just need to call the following:

```
logger = logging.getLogger(LOGGER_NAME)
```

Comment: this has an unused import, and more importantly this `init_logging` function seems to be just be a weaker version of something that python already has built in: [logging.basicConfig](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig)

Comment: Seems obvious that it would need to be called in __main__() somewhere at the start of the program...

Comment: But you **are** returning the `logger` from the function. I was going for that you probably meant: *you just need to call the following:* `logger = init_logging() `...

Comment: Edited for clarity.  You only need to call init_logging() once up front (yes it returns the logger, but that doesn't mean it should be called everywhere in the code).  Everywhere else you should call logging.getLogger(LOGGER_NAME) since the logger has at this point already been configured.