# How to save log file using Python?

Tags: python

I have a powershell script and I save the log using this way

```
$Log = Start-Transcript -Path $Log_Path -Force
```

How do I use it in Python?

Comment: Is your file available on the system after having called your powershell ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making Python loggers output all messages to stdout in addition to log file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14058453/making-python-loggers-output-all-messages-to-stdout-in-addition-to-log-file)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write/save the log file using the below command.

```
logging.basicConfig(filename='path to the log file', level=...)
```

There is a filemode option to overwrite the file.
To overwrite you can specifie filemode:w

```
logging.basicConfig(filename='logs.log',
            filemode='w',
            level=logging.INFO)
```

filemode: Specifies the mode to open the file, if filename is specified (if filemode is unspecified, it defaults to ‘a’).

Comment: this way I can save the log to file, but its not overwrite the log, how to make it overwrite?

Comment: Just add filemode:w to overwrite the file.

Answer (score 1):

There is a logging module in python. You can import an use that.

`import logging
 logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
 logging.debug('This will get logged')`

And the output will be:

`DEBUG:root:This will get logged`

Similarly, you can use the other log levels too. You can find more about it [here](https://realpython.com/python-logging/)

Comment: it does logged but it didnt write to file like the OP wants