# Presenting a file as the logs for a docker windows container

Tags: file, docker, logging, stdout, azure-container-instances

I'm setting up a windows container in ACI (Azure Container Instances). There's a logs tab in ACI, but it's not being used by my container since the application runs as a service detached from the stdout. How do I direct a log file to the logs tab (i.e. send to stdout).

I've read posts about redirecting log files to /dev/stdout for linux containers, but what about for windows containers? Is it as easy as writing the log file to a specific location?

Here's the logs tab I'm talking about inside ACI, I would like the log file written by my application to display inside here...

[image: Azure Container Instances logs tab]

(I know the container isn't running, this isn't the problem).

Comment: It's similar to the Linux. I don't know which language you use. But you need to use the stdout or stderr library in the language to get the logs yourself. Here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14058453/making-python-loggers-output-all-messages-to-stdout-in-addition-to-log-file) of Python.

Comment: @CharlesXu The log file being generated is a C# log file using log4net. I'm using a framework which uses log4net so sadly I didn't write the code that's creating the logs and therefore don't have control over it (unless log4net offers me the ability to redirect the logs to stdout?)