# How to get the terminal full history

Tags: python, cmd, terminal

I am trying to save everything my python app printed in the cmd, every solution I found was to get the response of a command line using `Popen` from `Subprocess`; what I want is to get everything. Is there a built-in function for this purpose? or should I do it manually, which I don't prefer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do, is log the output of stdout, see this answer:

[Making Python loggers output all messages to stdout in addition to log file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44760039/2508665)

Comment: I need to get the result in form of text to save it in a .txt file, does your code achieve that?

Comment: Yes, read up on stdout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385201/confused-about-stdin-stdout-and-stderr

Comment: I have been reading for an hour and didn't find what I want, are you sure. All what I found was to get a long response from a command.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use this from terminal

```
python main.py > output.log
```

Comment: I need the program to save it to a text file, I don't want to do it manually

Answer (score 0):

you can try the `script` command in your shell. It saves everything printed out to your shell from the moment you call it. End the command with exit. you can call it from your python script, hope it helps.

[script manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/script.1.html)

Comment: I need the program to save it to a text file, I don't want to do it manually