# GridSearchCV - save result each iteration

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, grid-search, hyperparameters

I'm using [GridSearchCV](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html), and after each iteration I want to save the `clf.cv_results_` property to a file, (just in case that the process will crash in the middle).

I tried looking for a solution but I just couldn't figure it out.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: please add some sample code and some elements of your dataset in order to help

Answer (score 7):

One of the ways to do it is to set the `verbose` parameter of your grid search to an integer higher than 0 like 10 or more, it will print the result for each iteration to the console.

With this, your output should be print or logged to your console, 
Then follow the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11325249/4683950) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513479/redirect-prints-to-log-file) question to see how to put the logged result to a file.

Basically, put this before running the `GridSearch`:

```
import sys
old_stdout = sys.stdout

log_file = open("message.log","w")

sys.stdout = log_file
```

Then after running your `GridSearch`, you should close all resources with this:

```
sys.stdout = old_stdout
log_file.close()
```