# Redirect everything in console to a log file including 'input' and 'os.system' function

Tags: python, python-3.x

My problem is similar as [redirect prints to log file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513479/redirect-prints-to-log-file)

When I started coding with Python last year, I didn't know about `logging` till now.
The problem is the code is getting bigger and bigger.

I've been trying solutions given, but none of them work properly as this code contains `input()`, `print()`, and `os.system()`

The closest solution was from `shx2` in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16551730/9013730) to [How to duplicate sys.stdout to a log file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/616645/how-to-duplicate-sys-stdout-to-a-log-file)

**Let's say this is the code**

```
import os, sys

class multifile(object):
    def __init__(self, files):
        self._files = files
    def __getattr__(self, attr, *args):
        return self._wrap(attr, *args)
    def _wrap(self, attr, *args):
        def g(*a, **kw):
            for f in self._files:
                res = getattr(f, attr, *args)(*a, **kw)
            return res
        return g

sys.stdout = multifile([ sys.stdout, open('log.txt', 'w') ])

name = input("\nWhat is your name: ")
print("Your name is",name)

age = input("\nHow old are you: ")
print("You're ",age)

print("\nYour IP Address is: ")
os.system('ipconfig | findstr IPv4')
```

**Console Output**

```
C:\>python script.py

What is your name: ABC
Your name is ABC

How old are you: 10
You're  10

Your IP Address is:
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 127.0.0.1

C:\>
```

`print` output from the console was redirected to `log.txt` without any problem, but not the `input` and `os.system`

**`log.txt` output**

```
What is your name: Your name is ABC

How old are you: You're  10

Your IP Address is:
```

Would it be possible to get everything (exactly the same) on the console to `log.txt`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Output on the console and file using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11325019/output-on-the-console-and-file-using-python)

Comment: does that work with `input` ??? I don't think so

Comment: have you tried ?

Comment: @Sabrina: do I understand correctly that you want the log file to contain *both* a copy of the program's output and a copy of the program's input? That is, you want the log to contain both what the program printed and what the user typed in response? In that case you'll not only need to hook `sys.stdout` but `sys.stdin` as well.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to redirect the output to a file

```
C:\>python script.py > filename.txt
```

I tried this and it seems to produce what you're looking for. Doing it this way though you won't the input prompts (e.g, 'What's your name' or 'How old are you') just a blank line with the cursor. See [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MI0Fm.gif) as an example.

Comment: My question: Would it be possible to get everything (exactly the same) on the console to log.txt?

This solution will print out nothing on the console. I would like to get similar output on both console and log file

Comment: How about just opening a file and writing to it as you the program is executed. Something like this:     `fileWriter = open('log.txt', 'w')

name = input('What is your name?: ')
fileWriter.write('What is your name?: ' + name + '\n')
print('Your name is', name)

age = input('How old are you?: ')
fileWriter.write('How old are you?: ' + age + '\n')
print('You\'re', age)`