# Redirect both 'print()' and 'os.system' to log file while maintaining the original output in console

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

I've been reading about [redirect prints to log file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513479/redirect-prints-to-log-file), however I did not understand why the accepted answer did not really work as expected.

The original code was in Python2, I've modified it a little bit as I'm working on Python3.

**Accepted Answer**:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2513511/9013730

```
import os

def test():
    cmd = 'ver'
    print("1. Running command:",cmd)    # message.log only, NOT in console
    os.system(cmd)                      # This appear in console only, but not in message.log
    print('3. Done')                    # message.log only, NOT in console

import sys
old_stdout = sys.stdout
log_file = open("message.log","w")
sys.stdout = log_file
print("This will be written to message.log")    # message.log only, NOT in console
test()
sys.stdout = old_stdout
log_file.close()
```

**Console Output**

As you can see, only `os.system(cmd)` printed out in console and I did not see it in message.log Output.

```
Microsoft Windows
```

**message.log Output**

When I checked message.log output, `os.system(cmd)` was not there.

```
This will be written to message.log
1. Running command: ver
3. Done
```

Would it be possible to produce similar (exact) output in both console and message.log?

**Desired Output in both console and message.log**

```
This will be written to message.log
1. Running command: ver
Microsoft Windows
3. Done
```

Comment: How about `python your_program.py > output.log`?

Comment: Thanks @KlausD. ... the final code will be converted to .exe ... so that's not really the option

Comment: Then I'd say you should use the logging and subprocess modules instead of `print` and `os.system`.

Comment: I've replaced `os.system(cmd)` with `subprocess.run(cmd, shell=True).stdout` but still can't see it on `message.log`