# What's the equivalence of os.fork() on Windows with Python?

Tags: python, fork

This code works well in Mac/Linux, but not in Windows.

```
import mmap
import os

map = mmap.mmap(-1, 13)
map.write("Hello world!")

pid = os.fork()

if pid == 0: # In a child process
    print 'child'
    map.seek(0)
    print map.readline()

    map.close()
else:
    print 'parent'
```

- What's the equivalent function of os.fork() on Windows?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on your use case and whether you can use python 2.6 or not, you might be able to use the [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html) module.

Answer (score 6):

The answer here may not answer the question.  The problem is due to `fork()`. From the example, you seemed want to share data between two Python scripts. Let me explain my view.

As of Python 3.8, there is no true Unix's `fork()` implementation in Windows platform. For the example above to work, a child process must inherit all environment and open file descriptors.

I understand that Windows now support Windows Linux Subsystem, but the last i checked it still does not fully implement fork. Cygwin does actually but it is a bit slow.

I do not know how, until now, to pass information between two Python scripts using mmap in Windows platform. Use

1. `multiprocessing.Queue` or
2. `multiprocessing.Pipe` or
3. `multiprocessing.Manager` or
4. `multiprocessing`'s shared memory (`Value` and `Array`) instead.

I believe you could make each Python script to read in content of the to-be-mapped file into `Array` of characters. Then use your own structure to map the shared memory into a structured data as you do for the to-be-mapped file.