# How to migrate the code snippet into Windows?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For the following code, since fork() method is not supported under Windows, I am wondering how to best migrate it to Windows?

```
import mmap
import os

mm = mmap.mmap(-1, 13)
mm.write(b"Hello world!")

pid = os.fork()

if pid == 0:  # In a child process
    mm.seek(0)
    print(mm.readline())

    mm.close()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the equivalence of os.fork() on Windows with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2738809/whats-the-equivalence-of-os-fork-on-windows-with-python)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2738809/whats-the-equivalence-of-os-fork-on-windows-with-python