# Python `tee` stdout of child process

Tags: python, file-io

Is there a way in Python to do the equivalent of the UNIX command line `tee`? I'm doing a typical fork/exec pattern, and I'd like the stdout from the child to appear in both a log file and on the stdout of the parent simultaneously without requiring any buffering.

In this python code for instance, the stdout of the child ends up in the log file, but not in the stdout of the parent.

```
pid = os.fork()
logFile = open(path,"w")
if pid == 0:
  os.dup2(logFile.fileno(),1)  
  os.execv(cmd)
```

**edit**: I do not wish to use the subprocess module. I'm doing some complicated stuff with the child process that requires me call `fork` manually.

Comment: Have you looked into the subprocess module? (http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here you have a working solution without using the `subprocess` module. Although, you could use it for the tee process while still using the `exec*` functions suite for your custom subprocess (just use `stdin=subprocess.PIPE` and then duplicate the descriptor to your stdout).

```
import os, time, sys

pr, pw = os.pipe()
pid = os.fork()

if pid == 0:
    os.close(pw)
    os.dup2(pr, sys.stdin.fileno())
    os.close(pr)
    os.execv('/usr/bin/tee', ['tee', 'log.txt'])
else:
    os.close(pr)
    os.dup2(pw, sys.stdout.fileno())
    os.close(pw)

    pid2 = os.fork()

    if pid2 == 0:
        # Replace with your custom process call
        os.execv('/usr/bin/yes', ['yes'])
    else:
        try:
            while True:
                time.sleep(1)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            pass
```

Note that the `tee` command, internally, does the same thing as Ben suggested in his answer: reading input and looping over output file descriptors while writing to them. It may be more efficient because of the optimized implementation and because it's written in C, but you have the overhead of the different pipes (don't know for sure which solution is more efficient, but in my opinion, reassigning a custom file-like object to `stdout` is a more elegant solution).

Some more resources:

- [How do I duplicate sys.stdout to a log file in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/616645/how-do-i-duplicate-sys-stdout-to-a-log-file-in-python)
- http://www.shallowsky.com/blog/programming/python-tee.html

Answer (score 6):

In the following, `SOMEPATH` is the path to the child executable, in a format suitable for `subprocess.Popen` (see its docs).

```
import sys, subprocess


f = open('logfile.txt', 'w')
proc = subprocess.Popen(SOMEPATH, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

while True:
    out = proc.stdout.read(1)
    if out == '' and proc.poll() != None:
        break
    if out != '':
        # CR workaround since chars are read one by one, and Windows interprets
        # both CR and LF as end of lines. Linux only has LF
        if out != '\r': f.write(out)
        sys.stdout.write(out)
        sys.stdout.flush()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But this requires buffering. Since I will be dealing with a large number of processes, this is something I'm trying to avoid. Also I'm trying to not use `subprocess` see edit.

Comment: @Mike: then you could probably use a separate thread to monitor the output and do what you need with it

Comment: There are alternative solutions, but I'm hoping there is something `tee`-like for the sake of simplicity

Answer (score 2):

Would an approach like this do what you want?

```
import sys

class Log(object):
    def __init__(self, filename, mode, buffering):
        self.filename = filename
        self.mode = mode
        self.handle = open(filename, mode, buffering)

    def write(self, thing):
        self.handle.write(thing)
        sys.stdout.write(thing)
```

You'd probably need to implement more of the `file` interface for this to be really useful (and I've left out properly defaulting `mode` and `buffering`, if you want it). You could then do all your writes in the child process to an instance of Log. Or, if you wanted to be really magic, and you're *sure* you implement enough of the `file` interface that things won't fall over and die, you could potentially assign `sys.stdout` to be an instance of this class. Then I *think* any means of writing to stdout, including `print`, will go via the log class.

**Edit to add:** Obviously if you assign to `sys.stdout` you will have to do something else in the `write` method to echo the output to stdout!! I think you could use `sys.__stdout__` for that.

Answer (score 2):

Oh, you. I had a decent answer all prettied-up before I saw the last line of your example: execv(). Well, poop. The original idea was replacing each child process' stdout with an instance of this blog post's tee class, and split the stream into the original stdout, and the log file:

http://www.shallowsky.com/blog/programming/python-tee.html

But, since you're using execv(), the child process' tee instance would just get clobbered, so that won't work.

Unfortunately for you, there is no "out of the box" solution to your problem that I can find. The closest thing would be to spawn the actual tee program in a subprocess; if you wanted to be more cross-platform, you could fork a simple Python substitute.

First thing to know when coding a tee substitute: tee really is a simple program. In all the true C implementations I've seen, it's not much more complicated than this:

```
while((character = read()) != EOF) {
    /* Write to all of the output streams in here, then write to stdout. */
}
```

Unfortunately, you can't just join two streams together. That would be really useful (so that the input of one stream would automatically be forwarded out of another), but we've no such luxury without coding it ourselves. So, Eli and I are going to have very similar answers. The difference is that, in my answer, the Python 'tee' is going to run in a separate process, via a pipe; that way, the parent thread is still useful!

(Remember: copy the blog post's tee class, too.)

```
import os, sys

# Open it for writing in binary mode.
logFile=open("bar", "bw")

# Verbose names, but I wanted to get the point across.
# These are file descriptors, i.e. integers.
parentSideOfPipe, childSideOfPipe = os.pipe()

# 'Tee' subprocess.
pid = os.fork()
if pid == 0:
    while True:
        char = os.read(parentSideOfPipe, 1)
        logFile.write(char)
        os.write(1, char)

# Actual command
pid = os.fork()
if pid == 0:
    os.dup2(childSideOfPipe, 1)
    os.execv(cmd)
```

I'm sorry if that's not what you wanted, but it's the best solution I can find.

Good luck with the rest of your project!

Answer (score 0):

The first obvious answer is to fork an actual tee process but that is probably not ideal.

The tee code (from coreutils) merely reads each line and writes to each file in turn (effectively buffering).