# Suppress newline in Python logging module

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

I'm trying to replace an ad-hoc logging system with Python's logging module.  I'm using the logging system to output progress information for a long task on a single line so you can `tail` the log or watch it in a console.  I've done this by having a flag on my logging function which suppresses the newline for that log message and build the line piece by piece.

All the logging is done from a single thread so there's no serialisation issues.

Is it possible to do this with Python's logging module?  Is it a good idea?

Comment: If you want to log multiple things in the same line consider not using `logging` for it but use a good old file object and write to it directly (and to a different file than the logfile used for other, line-based, things).

Comment: @ThiefMaster I'm writing to a file and stdout directly right now.  It feels like I'm rewriting logging though, so I'd rather use logging if it ends up being less effort.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Let's start with your last question: No, I do not believe it's a good idea. 
IMO, it hurts the readability of the logfile in the long run.

I suggest sticking with the [logging](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html) module and using the '-f' option on your 'tail' command to watch the output from the console. You will probably end up using the [FileHandler](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.handlers.html#filehandler). Notice that the default argument for 'delay' is False meaning the output won't be buffered.

If you *really* needed to suppress newlines, I would recommend creating your own Handler.

Answer (score 73):

If you wanted to do this you can change the logging handler terminator. I'm using Python 3.4. This was introduced in Python 3.2 as stated by Ninjakannon.

```
handler = logging.StreamHandler()
handler.terminator = ""
```

When the StreamHandler writes it writes the terminator last.

Comment: This was [introduced in Python 3.2](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#streamhandler).

Comment: How do I integrate this with the logger?

Comment: You don't. The handlers are the object that writes the information to a file, socket, stream, or other. Most handlers inherit from the StreamHandler. The terminator variable is a class level variable, so you can change this for all handlers with `logging.StreamHandler.terminator = ""`. This should change all handlers except ones where the terminator was explicitly set. You could also loop through the logger handlers and set the terminator `for handler in logger.handlers:`...

Comment: See [logging-cookbook](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html) in the docs for examples of using handlers. Looks like this answer needs something like `logging.getLogger('').addHandler(handler)` to be complete.

Comment: Using `terminator` works with `FileHandler` too.

Answer (score 13):

The new line, `\n`, is inserted inside the `StreamHandler` class.

If you're really set on *fixing* this behaviour, then here's an example of how I solved this by [monkey patching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch) the `emit(self, record)` method inside the logging.StreamHandler class.

> A monkey patch is a way to extend or modify the run-time code of dynamic languages without altering the original source code. This process has also been termed duck punching.

Here is the custom implementation of `emit()` that omits line breaks:

```
def customEmit(self, record):
    # Monkey patch Emit function to avoid new lines between records
    try:
        msg = self.format(record)
        if not hasattr(types, "UnicodeType"): #if no unicode support...
            self.stream.write(msg)
        else:
            try:
                if getattr(self.stream, 'encoding', None) is not None:
                    self.stream.write(msg.encode(self.stream.encoding))
                else:
                    self.stream.write(msg)
            except UnicodeError:
                self.stream.write(msg.encode("UTF-8"))
        self.flush()
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        raise
    except:
        self.handleError(record)
```

Then you would make a custom logging class (in this case, subclassing from `TimedRotatingFileHandler`).

```
class SniffLogHandler(TimedRotatingFileHandler):
    def __init__(self, filename, when, interval, backupCount=0,
                 encoding=None, delay=0, utc=0):

        # Monkey patch 'emit' method
        setattr(StreamHandler, StreamHandler.emit.__name__, customEmit)

        TimedRotatingFileHandler.__init__(self, filename, when, interval,
                                          backupCount, encoding, delay, utc)
```

Some people might argue that this type of solution is not *Pythonic*, or whatever. It might be so, so be careful.

Also, be aware that this will globally patch `SteamHandler.emit(...)`, so if you are using multiple logging classes, then this patch will affect the other logging classes as well!

Check out these for further reading:

- [What is monkey-patching?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5626193/what-is-monkey-patching)
- [Is monkeypatching considered good programming practice?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/144652)
- [Monkeypatching For Humans](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/07/monkeypatching-for-humans.html)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 11):

Python 3.5.9

```
class MFileHandler(logging.FileHandler):
  """Handler that controls the writing of the newline character"""

  special_code = '[!n]'

  def emit(self, record) -> None:

    if self.special_code in record.msg:
      record.msg = record.msg.replace( self.special_code, '' )
      self.terminator = ''
    else:
      self.terminator = '\n'

    return super().emit(record)
```

Then

```
fHandler = MFileHandler(...)
```

Example:

```
# without \n
log.info( 'waiting...[!n]' )
 ...
log.info( 'OK' )

# with \n
log.info( 'waiting...' )
 ...
log.info( 'OK' )
```

log.txt:

```
waiting...OK
waiting...
OK
```

Comment: Is this still the best way to do this?

Comment: @winderland For me, yes. But I would not recommend using this option if the logfile is filled from different threads.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered a need to log a certain section in a single line as I iterated through a tuple, but wanted to retain the overall logger.

Collected the output first into a single string and later sent it out to logger once I was out of the section. Example of concept

```
for fld in object._fields: 
  strX = (' {} --> {} ').format(fld, formattingFunction(getattr(obj,fld)))
debugLine += strX
logger.debug('{}'.format(debugLine))
```