# msgpack unpacks the number '10' between each item

Tags: python

I'm trying to use [msgpack](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/msgpack-python) to write a list of dictionaries to a file. However, when I iterate over an instance of `Unpacker`, it seems like the number `10` is unpacked between each 'real' document.

The test script I'm running is

```
import msgpack
from faker import Faker
import logging
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler

fake = Faker()
fake.seed(0)

data_file = "my_log.log"

logger = logging.getLogger('my_logger')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
handler = RotatingFileHandler(data_file, maxBytes=2000, backupCount=10)
logger.addHandler(handler)

fake_dicts = [{'name': fake.name()} for _ in range(100)]

for item in fake_dicts:
    dump_string = msgpack.packb(item)
    logger.debug(dump_string)

unpacker = msgpack.Unpacker(open(data_file))

for unpacked in unpacker:
    print unpacked
```

where I've used [fake-factory](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fake-factory) to generate fake data. The resulting printed output is as follows:

```
{'name': 'Joshua Carter'}
10
{'name': 'David Williams'}
10
{'name': 'Joseph Jones'}
10
{'name': 'Gary Perry'}
10
{'name': 'Terry Wells'}
10
{'name': 'Vanessa Cooper'}
10
{'name': 'Michael Simmons'}
10
{'name': 'Nicholas Kline'}
10
{'name': 'Lori Bennett'}
10
```

I don't understand why the number `10` is printed between each dictionary?  Is this somehow introduced by the `logger`?

Comment: My first thought is it is converting a line feed (Unicode 10) to an integer. Try `print msgpack.packb(item)` to print it directly, see if it's being introduced there or in the Unpacker.

Comment: It seems indeed that it is coming from the newline character introduced by the logger. I'm going to try to use `handler.terminator = ""` following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7168790/suppress-newline-in-python-logging-module (after upgrading to Python 3).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is coming from the contents of unpacker.  You can replicate yourself like this:

```
In [23]: unpacker = msgpack.Unpacker(open(data_file))

In [24]: unpacker.next()
Out[24]: {'name': 'Edward Ruiz'}

In [25]: unpacker.next()
Out[25]: 10
```

Comment: Any ideas on how I can prevent the `10`s from entering the `msgpack` in the first place?

Comment: I haven't used msgpack before, but I briefly looked at the spec here:  https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack/blob/master/spec.md.  This seems off first glance to be expected behavior in 30 seconds of looking.

Comment: Potentially a generator expression would handle this nicely:  http://www.dabeaz.com/generators/

Comment: I'm pretty sure the newline characters come from the `logger`, because in Python 3 in a version of the script using (human-readable) JSON instead of msgpack I can see the effect of the `handler.terminator = ""` command.

Comment: Maybe disable logging:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2266646/how-to-i-disable-and-re-enable-console-logging-in-python