# How to Redirect Python Stderr to String While Still Displaying

Tags: python

I'm capturing the stderr of my script to I can later save to a database via:

```
ostderr = sys.stderr
sys.stderr = StringIO()

# do stuff

mymodel.errors = sys.stderr.getvalue()
mymodel.save()
print mymodel.errors
sys.stderr = ostderr
```

Unfortunately, this makes casual debugging more difficult because if any errors occur, I won't see them until the script terminates.

How do I capture stderr in a string, as I'm doing above, but still display it in realtime to the console?

Comment: Just change stdout to stderr:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/616686/37205

Comment: @falcojr, For my app, I need to keep stdout and stderr separate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a file-like object that both saves and prints out to regular stderr. Something like:

```
class TeeFiles(object):
    def __init__(self, file):
        self.sio = StringIO()
        self.file = file

    def write(self, txt):
        self.sio.write(txt)
        self.file.write(txt)

sys.stderr = TeeFiles(sys.stderr)

# do stuff

mymodel.errors = sys.stderr.sio.getvalue()
mymodel.save()
sys.stderr = sys.stderr.file
```

You might need to support things like `closed`, `flush`, etc as well, depending on what happens in `#do stuff`. This might be easier if you inherited from `StringIO`.