# Python - printing to more than one output

Tags: python, io, python-2.7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I duplicate sys.stdout to a log file in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/616645/how-do-i-duplicate-sys-stdout-to-a-log-file-in-python)

Is it possible for Python `print` command or other Python command to print a string to two destinations? For example, I would like to print both to the console and to output file in one statement (so that I don't need to duplicate `print` statements).

Preferably, I'd like to have a solution for Python 2.x if that may matter.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Theoretically, you can try something like:

```
class Out(object):
    def write(self, s):
        sys.__stdout__.write(s)
        open('/tmp/log', 'a').write(s)

sys.stdout = Out()

...

print something # prints to stdout and logs
```

but a cleaner way would be  to abandon `print` and just use [logging](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html), because that is essentially what you want.

Comment: Wouldn't you want to close the log file after writing to it?

Comment: it should close automatically in the destructor

Comment: @carl, actually, I think it should close when it goes out of scope - at the end of `write`...

Comment: I think @carl meant to the destructor of `open('/tmp/log', 'a')`

Answer (score 2):

A comment to @carls's comment (I don't have reputation to comment yet):

From [Python's documentation](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files):

> It is good practice to use the [with](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) keyword when dealing with file objects. This has the advantage that the file is properly closed after its suite finishes, even if an exception is raised on the way. It is also much shorter than writing equivalent try-finally blocks:

```
>>> with open('/tmp/workfile', 'r') as f:
...     read_data = f.read()
>>> f.closed
True
```