# Getting HTML body with cgitb

Tags: python, cgi, cgitb

I'm using cgitb (python 2.7) to create html documents server end.  I have on file that does a bunch of query and then produces html.  I'd like to be able to link just the html so if I could print the html to a new file and link that that, it would work.

Is there a way to get the html the page will generate at the end of processing so that I can put it in a new file without keeping track of everything I've done so far along the way?

Edit: Found a snipped here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/616686/1576740

```
class Tee(object):
    def __init__(self, name, mode):
        self.file = open(name, mode)
        self.stdout = sys.stdout
        sys.stdout = self
    def __del__(self):
        sys.stdout = self.stdout
        self.file.close()
    def write(self, data):
        self.file.write(data)
        self.stdout.write(data)
```

You have to call it after you import cgi as it overrides stdout in what appears to be a less friendly way.  But works like a charm.

I just did import cgi;.......
Tee(filname, "w") and then I have a link to the file.

Comment: Are you using cgitb for its traceback abilities? Are you sure you don't just want cgi?

Answer (score 1):

From the [Python Documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/cgitb.html)

> Optionally, you can save this information to a file instead of sending it to the browser.

In this case you would want to use

```
cgitb.enable(display=1, logdir=directory)
```

Comment: This only seems to claim to print the tracebacks.  It also isn't working for me.  I'm doing cgitb.enable(1, '/tmp/test.html') and it isn't doing anything it seems, even on an error exit.

Comment: The directory, not the file

how are you using cgitb on non-error exits?

Comment: I don't think so.  How do I set it up for that?

Comment: So cgitb does error reporting, if your program works fine then cgitb never gets handled.

Perhaps you would like to tee your stdout?

Comment: This turned out to do exactly what I wanted:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/616686/1576740

Answer (score 0):

```
import cgitb
import sys

try:
    ...
except:
    with open("/path/to/file.html", "w") as fd:
        fd.write(cgitb.html(sys.exc_info()))
```