# Using python subprocess to fake running a cmd from a terminal

Tags: python, subprocess

We have a vendor-supplied python tool ( that's byte-compiled, we don't have the source ).  Because of this, we're also locked into using the vendor supplied python 2.4. The way to the util is:

```
source login.sh
oupload [options]
```

The login.sh just sets a few env variables, and then 2 aliases:

```
odownload () {
${PYTHON_CMD} ${OCLIPATH}/ocli/commands/word_download_command.pyc "$@"
}
oupload () {
${PYTHON_CMD} ${OCLIPATH}/ocli/commands/word_upload_command.pyc "$@"
}
```

Now, when I run it their way - works fine.  It will prompt for a username and password, then do it's thing.

I'm trying to create a wrapper around the tool to do some extra steps after it's run and provide some sane defaults for the utility.  The problem I'm running into is I cannot, for the life of me, figure out how to use subprocess to successfully do this.  It seems to realize that the original command isn't running directly from the terminal and bails.

I created a '/usr/local/bin/oupload' and copied from the original login.sh.  Only difference is instead of doing an alias at the end, I actually run the command.

Then, in my python script, I try to run my new shell script:

```
if os.path.exists(options.zipfile):
    try:
        cmd = string.join(cmdargs,' ')
        p1 = Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdin=PIPE)
```

But I get:

```
Enter Opsware Username: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./command.py", line 31, in main
File "./controller.py", line 51, in handle
File "./controllers/word_upload_controller.py", line 81, in _handle
File "./controller.py", line 66, in _determineNew
File "./lib/util.py", line 83, in determineNew
File "./lib/util.py", line 112, in getAuth
Empty Username not legal

Unknown Error Encountered                                              

SUMMARY:
Name: Empty Username not legal
Description: None
```

So it seemed like an extra carriage return was getting sent ( I tried rstripping all the options, didn't help ).

If I don't set stdin=PIPE, I get:

```
Enter Opsware Username: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./command.py", line 31, in main
File "./controller.py", line 51, in handle
File "./controllers/word_upload_controller.py", line 81, in _handle
File "./controller.py", line 66, in _determineNew
File "./lib/util.py", line 83, in determineNew
File "./lib/util.py", line 109, in getAuth
IOError: [Errno 5] Input/output error

Unknown Error Encountered
```

I've tried other variations of using p1.communicate, p1.stdin.write() along with shell=False and shell=True, but I've had no luck in trying to figure out how to properly send along the username and password.  As a last result, I tried looking at the byte code for the utility they provided - it didn't help - once I called the util's main routine with the proper arguments, it ended up core dumping w/ thread errors.

Final thoughts - the utility doesn't want to seem to 'wait' for any input.  When run from the shell, it pauses at the 'Username' prompt.  When run through python's popen, it just blazes thru and ends, assuming no password was given.  I tried to lookup ways of maybe preloading the stdin buffer - thinking maybe the process would read from that if it was available, but couldn't figure out if that was possible.

I'm trying to stay away from using pexpect, mainly because we have to use the vendor's provided python 2.4 because of the precompiled libraries they provide and I'm trying to keep distribution of the script to as minimal a footprint as possible - if I have to, I have to, but I'd rather not use it ( and I honestly have no idea if it works in this situation either ).

Any thoughts on what else I could try would be most appreciated.

**UPDATE**

So I solved this by diving further into the bytecode and figuring out what I was missing from the compiled command.

However, this presented two problems -

1. The vendor code, when called, was doing an exit when it completed
2. The vendor code was writing to stdout, which I needed to store and operate on ( it contains the ID of the uploaded pkg ).  I couldn't just redirect stdout, because the vendor code was still asking for the username/password.

1 was solved easy enough by wrapping their code in a try/except clause.

2 was solved by doing something similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/616672/677373

Instead of a log file, I used cStringIO.  I also had to implement a fake 'flush' method, since it seems the vendor code was calling that and complaining that the new obj I had provided for stdout didn't supply it - code ends up looking like:

```
class Logger(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.terminal = sys.stdout
        self.log = StringIO()

    def write(self, message):
        self.terminal.write(message)
        self.log.write(message)

    def flush(self):
        self.terminal.flush()
        self.log.flush()

if os.path.exists(options.zipfile):
    try:
        os.environ['OCLI_CODESET'] = 'ISO-8859-1'
        backup = sys.stdout
        sys.stdout = output = Logger()
        # UploadCommand was the command found in the bytecode
        upload = UploadCommand()
        try:
            upload.main(cmdargs)
        except Exception, rc:
            pass
        sys.stdout = backup
        # now do some fancy stuff with output from output.log
```

I should note that the only reason I simply do a 'pass' in the except: clause is that the except clause is *always* called.  The 'rc' is actually the return code from the command, so I will probably add handling for non-zero cases.

Comment: If you found an acceptable answer then you could post it as an answer and accept it. To fake terminal if you don't want to use pexpect module you could try `pty` module from stdlib, [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12471855/4279) (set both stdin/stdout and write/read in the loop in your case)

Comment: Well, my 'answer' didn't truly answer the question - which is how to fake the terminal.  I got *around* it by not bothering with it.  I believe using 'pty' may work though, so I'd actually prefer your solution as a true answer to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to lookup ways of maybe preloading the stdin buffer

Do you perhaps want to create a named fifo, fill it with username/password info, then reopen it in read mode and pass it to popen (as in `popen(..., stdin=myfilledbuffer)`)?

You could also just create an ordinary temporary file, write the data to it, and reopen it in read mode, again, passing the reopened handle as stdin. (This is something I'd personally avoid doing, since writing username/passwords to temporary files is often of the bad. OTOH it's easier to test than FIFOs)

As for the underlying cause: I suspect that the offending software is reading from stdin via a non-blocking method. Not sure why that works when connected to a terminal.

AAAANYWAY: no need to use pipes directly via Popen at all, right? I kinda laugh at the hackishness of this, but I'll bet it'll work for you:

```
# you don't actually seem to need popen here IMO -- call() does better for this application.
statuscode = call('echo "%s\n%s\n" | oupload %s' % (username, password, options) , shell=True)
```

tested with `status = call('echo "foo\nbar\nbar\nbaz" |wc -l', shell = True)` (output is '4', naturally.)

Comment: Tried the call method w/ the shell pipe and the tempfile, neither worked ( both threw different errors, however ).  Tried to do the named pipes and this resulted in some strange behaviour - the script now seems to 'pause' at the username prompt, however, any keystroke causes a return to shell, but the process remains running in the background.  Also, interestingly enough, the oupload process displays its parent pid as init, rather than the python wrapper, even though both are still running.

Answer (score 0):

The original question was solved by just avoiding the issue and not using the terminal and instead importing the python code that was being called by the shell script and just using that.

I believe J.F. Sebastian's answer would probably work better for what was originally asked, however, so I'd suggest people looking for an answer to a similar question look down the path of using the pty module.