# Subprocess fails to print after one usage

Tags: python, subprocess

I've been developing software that opens a cmd, and lets another user control it like ssh. I want that to respect things like cd, and not just throw them away, like using multiple processes does; so i have used one sub-process. However, problem arises when trying to pipeline the output of the sub-process more than once: it just returns ""! Please help!

RELEVANT CODE:

```
print("attempting to open subprocesses")
process = Popen("echo \"im alive!\"", shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
process.wait()

process.stdin.write(bytes(data, "utf-8"))
process.wait()
while True:
     print("..inloop")
     output = process.stdout.readline().decode("utf-8")
     if output == '' and process.poll() is not None:
          break
     if output:
          print("outputting")
     hc.broadcast_data("sentinelkey", output, connections, 
server_socket)
```

Comment: What's the expected behavior? It's not clear to me what your code is intended to do.

Comment: I think https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13243523/using-python-subprocess-to-fake-running-a-cmd-from-a-terminal?rq=1 this will be interesting for you.

Comment: @Elliott , it's intended to basically work like this:
(in data from somewhere else) -> (fake a cmd call for this data, and keep this subproccess open for future data) -> (send back the output of the cmd)

Comment: Are you using windows or linux ?

Comment: i have both os's, but i have been testing on windows.