# How to arrange print output from Python Wavelets package

Tags: python, output, export-to-csv, wavelet

I have the output from Python wavelet package:

```
 [[[[[[255 255 255 255]
 [255 255 255 255]
 [255 255 255 255]
 ..., 
 [255 255 255 255]
 [255 255 255 255]
 [255 255 255 255]]

[[255 255 255 255]
 [255 255 255 255]
 [255 255 255 255]
 ..., 
 [255 255 255 255]
 [255 255 255 255]
 [255 255 255 255]]

[[255 255 255 255]
 [255 255 255 255]
 [255 255 255 255]
 ..., 
 [255 255 255 255]
 [255 255 255 255]
 [255 255 255 255]]

..., 
[[255 255 255 255]
 [255 255 255 255]
 [255 255 255 255]
 ..., 
 [255 255 255 255]
 [255 255 255 255]
 [255 255 255 255]]

[[255 255 255 255]
 [255 255 255 255]
 [255 255 255 255]
 ..., 
 [255 255 255 255]
 [255 255 255 255]
 [255 255 255 255]]

[[255 255 255 255]
 [255 255 255 255]
 [255 255 255 255]
 ..., 
 [255 255 255 255]
 [255 255 255 255]
 [255 255 255 255]]]]]]
```

I need  to print it to terminal and to a `.csv` file in one line with tab separation and without brackets.

```
 def waveletdbbiorone(self):     #function for Wavelets computation
     for filename in glob.iglob ('*.tif'):
         imgwbior = mahotas.imread (filename) #read the image
         arraywbior = numpy.array([imgwbior])#make an array for pywt module
         coefwbior = pywt.wavedec(arraywbior,'db1')#compute wavelet coefficients
         arr = numpy.array([coefwbior])
         np.set_printoptions(precision=3)
         print arr
```

Comment: If you on Unix/Linux you can use tee. See similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/616645/how-do-i-duplicate-sys-stdout-to-a-log-file-in-python

Comment: that is not the answer to my question

Comment: yes, that is correct. It's not an answer it is a comment and was meant to be.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want only one line use the iterator `flat`:

Python 3

```
>>> for elem in arr.flat:
        print('{}\t'.format(elem), end='')  
    255.0   255.0   255.0   255.0   255.0 .........
```

Python 2

```
>>> for elem in arr.flat:
        print '{}\t'.format(elem),
    255.0   255.0   255.0   255.0   255.0 .........
```