# Capturing output from nose.run()

Tags: python, nose

I'd like to capture the output that nose.run() prints to stdout so I can send it in an email if tests fail. I believe the LogCapture plugin does what I want, so I'm doing:

```
logcap = nose.plugins.logcapture.LogCapture()
success = nose.run(argv=[".", '-x'], plugins=[logcap])
```

The [documentation for logcapture](https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plugins/logcapture.html) says that the captured log is saved to the `test.capturedLogging` attribute. The trouble is I have no idea where that is - it's not on my logcap object above, and nose.run() only returns a boolean.

Is there a way to do what I want?

Comment: Turns out I was labouring under the misunderstanding that nose prints its outputs to stdout - it actually prints to stderr.

I found [this snippet](http://stackoverflow.com/a/616686/2941784) useful, with a change to make it dupe stderr rather than stdout.

Comment: You surely can make nose email you on error, but you may benefit dramatically by switching to some sort of Continuous Integration (I like jenkins/nose with xunit combo https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plugins/xunit.html). You will get nice reports too!

Comment: Yeah - we're using jenkins for plenty of things, but this is a quick sanity check I threw together before we get a more formal end-to-end test together.