# Printing stdout while also printing to a text file in python

Tags: python, file, stdout

Is there any way to print stdout while at the same time also printing to a text file? For example:

```
import sys
sys.stdout = open('file.txt', 'w')
#The stuff below should be printed out and at the same time being printed to a text file
print "This is in a text file and stdout"
```

So, once again, is there any way to do this? Or can it not be done?

Comment: `tee` - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/616645/how-do-i-duplicate-sys-stdout-to-a-log-file-in-python

Comment: Do you need a multiplatform solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is in a script, have a look at the unix command `tee`. This will allow you to split `stdout` into two directions, one that goes to a file, and one that simply continues to `stdout`

Comment: (I am a python newb) Example?

Comment: @TheNotGoodAtCodeGuy `python myscript | tee mylog.txt` will run a script named `myscript.py`, write `stdout` to `mylog.txt`, and also print `stdout` to your console

Comment: Sorry, had to leave to go to something for a while.