# Python redirect subprocess to file and to console

Tags: python, windows, subprocess

Using Python, I want to create a subprocess and have its output redirected to both a file **AND** the console.

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/616645/how-do-i-duplicate-sys-stdout-to-a-log-file-in-python) explaining how to print to both console and file, but solutions does not work when creating a subprocess:

```
sys.stdout = Logger()
print( "Hello") # printed to console and file
res = subprocess.call(cmd) # command output is printed to console only
```

Same behaviour here:

```
with Tee('outfile.log', 'w'):
    print( "Hello" )
    res = subprocess.call(cmd)
```

How can I redirect subprocess output both to console (for user) and to file (for me to check it from my code).

Note: Im' on Windows, so using system's `tee` is not appropriate.

Comment: `subprocess.call(cmd, stdout=Logger())`?

Comment: @hlt: Tried that, but does not work, it reports errors about Logger not being of the proper type....

Comment: check out this: https://github.com/waszil/subpiper

Answer (score 4):

Connect `cmd`'s standard output to `tee`'s stdin:

```
# cmd = ['/bin/echo', 'blah blah']
tee = subprocess.Popen(['/usr/bin/tee', 'outfile.log'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
subprocess.call(cmd, stdout=tee.stdin)
tee.stdin.close()
```

**UPDATE** For systems that does not have `tee`, read the output of the command and write it into stdout, and the log file:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
                        universal_newlines=True)

with open('outfile.log', 'w') as f:
    while True:
        data = proc.stdout.read(1024)
        if not data:
            break
        sys.stdout.write(data)
        f.write(data)
```

Comment: I'm on Windows. Need a more generic solution. Sorry, I'll update OP.

Comment: @jpo38, I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Tried it, got an error `sys.stdout.write(data)` `TypeError: must be str, not bytes`. Tried `str(data)` but then `\r\n` are being displayed and output comes on a single line....

Comment: Moreover, it's hard to decide what read parameter should be, 1024 may be way to much for processes writing few data. The `while True` loop may change the timing in which process output comes to the console...

Comment: Instead of using str(data), use `data.decode("utf-8")` or `data.decode("ascii")`

Comment: Works....but only for `stdout`, how to handle `stderr` to have ALL outputs!?

Comment: As shown in the code, by specifying `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT`, you will get standard error output with standard output.

Comment: plus one for the 2nd code example. You should close `proc.stdout` in the 1st one otherwise `cmd` might hang if `tee` dies. Or use `tee = Popen(['tee', 'logfile'], stdin=PIPE); call(cmd, stdout=tee.stdin)` See [How do I use subprocess.Popen to connect multiple processes by pipes?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9164238/4279)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, Thank you for the comment. Closing `proc.stdout` seems inappropriate; closing before `call` will cause IOError. closing afterward- no benefit. I updated the answer to use your second suggestion.

Comment: @falsetru: 1. obviously, you would use `Popen()` instead of `call()`, to close the pipe (`p.stdout`) in time. 2. You could call `tee.communicate()` after the `call()`

Comment: @eryksun, Thank you for the comment, I updated the answer accordingly. I didn't know about `universal_newlines`.