# Save unittest results in text file

Tags: python, unit-testing

I'm writing code that tests via unittest if several elements exist on a certain homepage. After the test I want that the results were saved in a text file. But the results in the text file look like this:

```
......................
.........

------------------------------------------
Ran 12 tests in 22.562s
OK.
```

But i want that the output looks like this:

```
test_test1 (HomepageTest.HomePageTest) ... ok
test_test2 (HomepageTest.HomePageTest) ... ok
test_test3 (HomepageTest.HomePageTest) ... ok
etc....
-------------------------------------------------
Ran 12 tests in ...s
OK
```

This is the code I use for saving the output into a text file:

```
class SaveTestResults(object):
    def save(self):
       self.f = open(log_file, 'w')
       runner = unittest.TextTestRunner(self.f)
       unittest.main(testRunner = runner, defaultTest ='suite', verbosity = 2)
    
def main():
    STR = SaveTestResults()
    STR.save()

if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know this module, does the output you wish to have correspond to the output printed out to the console?

Comment: the console print out nothing, when i remove the function **def save()** the console print out the output i want to have. But the code doesn´t save the output the way i want it

Comment: If the console originally prints out what you're looking for, then redirecting `stdout` to a file will do the trick. Have a look at my answer, I think it should at least give you the basic idea.

Answer (score 3):

If the output you wish to save in a file corresponds to what is printed out to the console, you have two main options.

#### 1 - You're using Linux

Then just redirect the output to a file:

```
python script.py > output.txt
```

However, the output will not be printed out to the console anymore.
If you want to keep the console output, use the `tee` unix command:

```
python script.py | tee output.txt
```

#### 2 - You're using Windows, or you don't want to redirect the whole output to a file

You can achieve more or less the same thing using exclusively Python.
You need to set the value of `sys.stdout` to the file descriptor where you want the output to be written.

```
import sys
sys.stdout = open("output.txt", 'w')

run_tests()
```

This will set the output stream `stdout` to the given file for the whole script.
I would suggest defining a decorator instead:

```
def redirect_to_file(func):

    def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
        actualStdout = sys.stdout
        sys.stdout = open("log.txt", 'a')
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        sys.stdout = actualStdout

        return result

    return decorated
```

Then, just decorate the functions whose you want to write the output to a file:

```
@redirect_to_file
def run_test():
    ...
```

If you want a similar behaviour to `tee`, have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/616686/7051394).
The idea is to define a `Tee` class that holds the two desired streams:

```
class Tee:
    def __init__(self, stream1, stream2):
        self.stream1 = stream1
        self.stream2 = stream2

    def write(self, data):
        self.stream1.write(data)
        self.stream2.write(data)

    def close(self):
        self.stream1.close()
        self.stream2.close()
```

Then, set `sys.stdout` to a `Tee` instance whose one of the stream is the actual `stdout`:

```
tee = Tee(sys.stdout, open("output.txt", 'w'))
sys.stdout = tee
```

Don't forget to close the `tee` instance at the end of your script; else, the data written to `output.txt` will not be saved:

```
tee.close()
```

Comment: tried it, but unfortunatly the output is still the same, i´m using windows and work on cloud9

Comment: @diem_L What did you try exactly? You said that the `save` method was preventing any output to the console. You need to restore the console output as desired before implementing any of the methods I proposed to you.