# saving output with sys.stdout, but I want to show it on console/terminal

Tags: python

So for analysis, I want to save everything the scripts outputs on the console/terminal, and for that I used `sys.stdout`:

*My code:*

```
sys.stdout = open('logFile.dat', 'w')
# TOO MUCH LINES OF CODE
sys.stdout.close()
```

My program is quite large, and there isn't point to copy-paste it here, because It doesn't affect my question.

So with this I get what I wanted but on the other hand, the console is blank while the program is running and that is a problem for me, because I want for program to output stuff on the console.

Is there anyway to get past this ?

Comment: So, you want to output to both console and file?

Comment: @Blorgbeard exactly

Comment: Some options here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/616645/how-to-duplicate-sys-stdout-to-a-log-file

Comment: assign `stdout` to other variable `original_stdout = sys.stdout` and use `original_stdout.write("text\n")` to write on console. OR if you do this because you want to redicrect `print()` to file then you can use `print("text", file=file_handler)`. OR use module `logging` to send messages on screen and save in file.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I'd have used regular stdout and `tee`

Let's say you have code: `simple.py`

```
print("Hello")
```

You can run it like this

```
> python ./simple.py  | tee output.log
Hello
> cat output.log
Hello
```

And you have both - messages on console and log file.

**Logger based approach**

This is not exactly what you are looking for, but you still can run it such way you will get results in both: console and file

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger('simple')
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

std_out = logging.StreamHandler()
file_out = logging.FileHandler('file.log')

logger.addHandler(std_out)
logger.addHandler(file_out)

logger.info('Hello from code')
```

and you will get following

```
> python ./simple.py
Hello from code
> cat file.log
Hello from code
```

Comment: It's a nice solution, but I'm using Windows

Comment: in [GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm) you can find `tee` and `cat` for Windows

Answer (score 0):

Changing sys.stdout to be a custom stream (file) is a little extreme. A couple of options:
1. Do the redirection on the command line. If you are using bash (linux / mac / etc) you can pipe the output to the "tee" program, e.g.

`python my_program.py | tee logfile.txt`

tee is a simple program that takes its input (stdin) and writes it to stdout as well as a file of your choosing.

2. Instead of using print(), create a logging class and use that to print output. Modify your logging class to write to both sys.stdout and your log file, depending on configuration. See also the [logging](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) docs.
3. More advanced and hacky: create your own File implementation that acts like the"tee" program and forwards its write() etc. calls to two underlying files: sys.stdout and your file for the log file.

Comment: Well I can't use tee, because I'm using Windows, but will try your other suggestions