# Python log everything that passes through command prompt

Tags: python, logging

I am trying to log **everything** that passes through my command prompt. This includes batch script output that is launched by the python script.

If I run my python file like this

```
python logEverything.py >> logFile.txt
```

It gives me what I want and everything that is printed in the command prompt will instead be put into that file.

The problem with this is it no longer shows anything in the command prompt. Additionally I would like to be able to specify the logfile path inside of the program.

So is there a way to log everything that passes through the command prompt **utilizing Python**? Compatible for windows and Linux?

So logEverything.py would be something like this

```
import sys
def main():
    import io
    old_stdout = sys.stdout # Memorize the default stdout stream
    sys.stdout = buffer = io.StringIO()


    print('Log test')
    os.system('this is a test')
    print('More logging')


    #Finished -> put everything into log_file.txt
    sys.stdout = old_stdout
    whatWasPrinted = buffer.getvalue() 
    print(whatWasPrinted) # Why not to print it?
    buffer.close()
```

This solution partially works but it does not capture the output from the os.system()

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to duplicate sys.stdout to a log file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/616645/how-to-duplicate-sys-stdout-to-a-log-file)

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy that answer is not compatible on a Windows system

Comment: Nothing in your question mentions Windows. Please [edit] your question to elaborate on why the proposed duplicate in not suitable.

Comment: Why not just log to file _and_ terminal?

Comment: @hoefling Like use my logging function to log the message and also do a print() statement? There is many more commands that just those three up there and doing both would get sloppy. Also I don't think that would capture the output of the batch file.

Comment: Now you have changed the question and it's not clear anymore what the `logMessage` function is listed for. I'd suggest removing the fuzz, leaving only the related stuff. If it's about capturing the output of a subprocess, then it's surely possible with Python: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760215/running-shell-command-and-capturing-the-output

Comment: Yea, sorry about that, trying to better convey what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/731237/853825) question on askubuntu:

> `command |& tee -a output.txt`
>
> Both the standard output and standard error streams will be copied to the file while still being visible in the terminal. If the file already exists, the new data will get appended to the end of the file.

So you could use `python logEverything.py |& tee -a logFile.text`

Comment: Do you know how to make this compatible on a windows system?