# Python PDB interactive mode breaks when redirecting sys.stdout

Tags: python, pdb

After replacing `sys.stdout` with a [Tee logger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/616645/how-to-duplicate-sys-stdout-to-a-log-file) (to redirect output to a file), PDB no longer works properly. For example, pressing the up arrow produces `^[[A` instead of the previous command.

The problem can be reproduced using this snippet:

```
import sys
import pdb

class Tee(object):
    def __init__(self, name, mode):
        self.file = open(name, mode)
        self.stdout = sys.stdout
        sys.stdout = self
    def __del__(self):
        sys.stdout = self.stdout
        self.file.close()
    def write(self, data):
        self.file.write(data)
        self.stdout.write(data)
    def flush(self):
        self.file.flush()

sys.stdout = Tee('test.txt', 'w')
pdb.set_trace()
```

Is there any way to replace `sys.stdout` without breaking PDB?

Comment: Once you replace `stdout` with the tee, it is no longer a terminal, and PDB's readline cannot support any interactivity except typing characters. Logically it is reasonable: you can't edit output both on the screen and in the tee'd file. I would suggest changing the code that writes to stdout so that it wrote to a given file instead, and tee _that_ file, so that you could see it both on the console and in a hard-copy file.

Comment: The latter is impractical for me because that would involve changing every print into a custom log function in a large codebase. I'm not sure what you mean by "it's no longer a terminal" -- can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

(1) You cannot have interactivity on the tee'd output because it's a regular stream, and not a terminal. A terminal allows to do a ton of things: position the cursor, erase contents, read keys, echo keypresses to the screen, etc. A regular file on a disk can't do all these things, this is why `pdb` fails to do these things in interactive mode. You can check that `sys.stdout.isatty()` returns `True` is you run a REPL.

(2) You can of course change every `print` *function invocation* in your code to write to stdout *and* to whatever file you want, because you can redefine `print`. This works in Python 3, and in Python 2.7 if you `from __future__ import print`. Then you can do things like this:

```py
system_print = print  # preserve the original.

def print_also_to(other_file):
  def tee_print(*args, **kwargs):
    system_print(*args, **kwargs)  # Normally prints to stdout.  
    system_print(*args, **kwargs, file=other_file)  # Write a copy.
  return tee_print

print = print_also_to(open('/tmp/copy-of-stdout'))  # A crude example.

print("Hello world!")  # Unmodified code.
```

With `print` *statements*, your situation is worse. Use [`strace` on Linux](https://linux.die.net/man/1/strace) or `DTrace` on macOS to capture the writing to stdout (and elsewhere) and redirect it to a file when starting your process:

```
strace -e trace=write -o writes.txt python your-script.py
```

It will write to the file something like `write(1, 'Hello world!')`. You would need to parse it and reconstruct output to stdout (1) specifically to produce a real copy of the output.

I suppose `pdb`'s interactive mode will work under this, too; at the very least, Python REPL works fine under strace.