# Redirect stdout to file, but only within a certain class

Tags: python, stdout

There are a ton of resources on how to manage `sys.stdout` so that it prints to either just a file or tees to both a file and `sys.stdout`. However, my use case is different.

I am using code from a code base that uses `print` calls, and it would take too long to swap it out for a logger. Instead, I created a custom `Tee` class to duplicate output from `print` calls to a log file. It worked fine for the synchronous case.

Template for `Tee` class: [How to duplicate sys.stdout to a log file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/616645/how-to-duplicate-sys-stdout-to-a-log-file)

However, I adapted the code to use multiple threads at once using the `multiprocessing` module. Because of this, I am unable to track which thread the `print` calls are coming from, and therefore which `Tee` to use.

It would be really useful to be able to redirect `print` calls, but only from within a certain block of code. For example, if I create a `Tee` class inside a function and then delete it, then all `print` calls within that function and their children would redirect to a specific file, whereas if I create a `Tee` class inside another thread, the same would happen.

I can imagine a complicated class using locks and synchronization to manage everything, but I am stuck on how to determine the origin of the `print` calls. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you aware of [`contextlib.redirect_stdout`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout)?

Comment: @chepner I am not, but that seems to have some useful functionality I should explore! It isn't thread safe but I could probably figure out a way to make it work. Thanks!