# Why does my revectored sys.stdout.write() method get called after I've unlinked it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, spyder

I wrote a `tee()` class, which redirects stdout to both the terminal and a file, based on Triptych's answer at [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/616645/how-do-i-duplicate-sys-stdout-to-a-log-file-in-python](https://www.spyder-ide.org/).

It works the first couple of times my program runs, but the 3rd time I get:

```
  File "C:\Users\Dave\data\Code\Python\lib\nerdlib.py", line 351, in write
    with open(self.name, "a",  encoding="utf-8") as f:

TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
```

It seems that even after I do `sys.stdout = self.old_stdout` (restoring the execution vector to the place it started from), somehow my write method is still getting called (in which case the error is expected).

But *why* is my method still getting called?

This error occurs in the [Spyder](https://www.spyder-ide.org/) development environment - not sure if that's related.

Code is below - it's simple enough.

```
# based on Triptych's answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/616645/how-do-i-duplicate-sys-stdout-to-a-log-file-in-python
class tee():
    ''' Tees stdout to both a log file and the terminal.

        if append is True (default), appends to existing file

        if stderr is True (default), tees stederr to same file

        Usage:
            t = tee("filename.txt")
            ...
            print(1, 2, 3)
            ...
            t.__del__() # returns sys.stdout to original state
    '''

    def __init__(self, filepath, append=True, stderr=True):

        self.old_stdout = sys.stdout
        self.old_stderr = sys.stderr
        self.name = filepath

        if (not append) or (not os.path.exists(self.name)):
            makeEmptyFile(self.name)

        sys.stdout = self

        if stderr:
            sys.stderr = self

    def write(self, text):

        self.old_stdout.write(text)

        # open file, write, then close it again (slow, but safe - permits other processes to write to same file)
        with open(self.name, "a",  encoding="utf-8") as f:
           f.write(text)

    def flush(self):
        pass

    def stop(self):
        sys.stdout = self.old_stdout
        sys.stdout = self.old_stderr
        self.name = None

    def __del__(self):
        self.stop()
```

Comment: @CharlesDuffy But `self.name = None` only happens AFTER the `sys.stdout = self.old_stdout`, which restores the stdout to run the old code. My write method should't be getting called at all after that. (Unless I'm terribly confused.)

Comment: Ahh, gotcha. Thing is, `sys.stdout = self.old_stdout` only works for code that's going through the `sys` module every time it wants to do a write.

Comment: Let's say you've got a thread started with an initializer that's something like `class MyThread(threading.Thread): def __init__(self, log_dest=sys.stdout, ...)` -- that `log_dest` won't magically change back for any already-started copy of the thread. That's just an example, intended to provide a demonstration that it's not safe to assume that there are no remaining handles after you change the sys module's reference back.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Ya, that's probably it. Makes sense. I'll test a mod with that in mind - if it works you should make that an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The danger here is that setting `sys.stdout = sys.old_stdout` stops code from getting a *new* handle on the local replacement, but it doesn't stop any *old* handle from working.

As a contrived example:

```
class MyThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, log_dest=sys.stdout):
        self.log_dest = log_dest
    def run(self):
        # ...do something-or-other, and occasionally...
        self.log_dest.write('Hey, something happened')
```

Because `log_dest` gets assigned a value *when MyThread was initialized*, changing `sys.stdout` back to its old value doesn't prevent it from still trying to use your now-invalidated object.

Comment: Yes, that was it. Changing the write method to do simply `print(text)` if `self.name is None` seems to fix it. Tricky thing to get this to work reliably.