# Python Unittest - Write unittest results to both console AND text file

Tags: python, unit-testing, console, text-files, python-unittest

I found the below code here on stackoverflow in order to write my python unittest results to a text file.  Per the python unittest documentation the first argument in `unittest.TextTestRunner` is the stream.  So, `f` which represents the text file is where the output goes.  When I run this I see that the console no longer displays the output.  How can I get the unittest results to display in both the **console** AND the **text file** at the same time?  Thank you very much.

```
log_file = 'log_file.txt'
with open(log_file, "w") as f:
    runner = unittest.TextTestRunner(f, verbosity=2)
    unittest.main(testRunner=runner)
```

Comment: It looks like many people prefer to leave the std.out stream alone in the python code and use the operating system, specifically in Unix ,`tee`, to log a copy of the screen output to a file. See [How to duplicate sys.stdout to a log file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/616645/how-to-duplicate-sys-stdout-to-a-log-file)

Comment: Please consider splitting into two questions, since you ask two questions.

Comment: @PeterK Created separate question per your suggestion.  Thanks.